# Scala: how can I sort an array of tuples by their second element?

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting, tuples

is there a way in Scala to sort an array of tuples using and arbitrary comparison function? In particular I need to sort and array of tuples by their second element, but I wanted to know a general technique to sort arrays of tuples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
scala> val v = Array(('a', 2), ('b', 1))
v: Array[(Char, Int)] = Array((a,2), (b,1))

scala> scala.util.Sorting.stableSort(v,
     | (e1: (Char, Int), e2: (Char, Int)) => e1._2 < e2._2)

scala> v
res11: Array[(Char, Int)] = Array((b,1), (a,2))
```

Unfortunetly, it seems that Scala cannot infer the type of the array passed to `stableSort`. I hope that's ok for you.

Comment: Bit nicer: `stableSort(v, (_._2 < _._2) : ((Char,Int),(Char,Int)) => Boolean)` — keeps the concerns separate, and allows one to reason about the logic and the types as independent steps, especially since the inline type signature is only a nuisance here.

Comment: One things to note is that if you are dealing with the Any type in the sort column (suppose it has Long) you need to do: scala.util.Sorting.stableSort(v, (e1: (String, Any), e2: (String, Any)) => e1._2.asInstanceOf[Long] < e2._2.asInstanceOf[Long])

Answer (score 140):

In scala 2.8, there is a method sortBy. Here is a simple use case:

```
scala> val arr = Array(("One",1),("Two",2),("Four",4),("Three",3))
arr: Array[(java.lang.String, Int)] = Array((One,1), (Two,2), (Four,4), (Three,3))

scala> arr.sortBy(_._2)
res0: Array[(java.lang.String, Int)] = Array((One,1), (Two,2), (Three,3), (Four,4))

scala>
```

Comment: 2.8 is just plain cheating. +1

Comment: Gooood. I'll have to switch to 2.8 (currently using 2.7) Thanks

Comment: This does not sort in place, however.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, and I just wrote  a post about it: http://old.nabble.com/Is-it-possible-to-use-filter-or-sort-method-of-a-mutable-Seq-without-creating-new-Seq--td28222943.html

Answer (score 9):

If it's an `Array`, it's probably typical to use in-place sorting algorithms. However, in idiomatic Scala code, mutable collections are usually not encouraged/used. If that's the case and you have am immutable collection (or would like to not modify the `Array` in place), use `sortWith`:

```
scala> val a = Array(1, 3, 2, 5)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 3, 2, 5)

scala> a.sortWith(_ > _)
res6: Array[Int] = Array(5, 3, 2, 1)

scala> a
res7: Array[Int] = Array(1, 3, 2, 5)
```

sorting an `Array` or any other collection of tuples:

```
scala> val a = Array(('a', 1), ('b', 4), ('c', 5), ('d', 2))
a: Array[(Char, Int)] = Array((a,1), (b,4), (c,5), (d,2))

scala> a.sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
res4: Array[(Char, Int)] = Array((c,5), (b,4), (d,2), (a,1))

scala> a
res5: Array[(Char, Int)] = Array((a,1), (b,4), (c,5), (d,2))
```

Comment: where can we find about about that "_._2" syntax? What is that called?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Answer (score 3):

On Scala 2.8 (yes, again :), you can also do this:

```
val v = Array(('a', 2), ('b', 1))
scala.util.Sorting.stableSort(v)(manifest[(Char, Int)], Ordering.by(_._2))
```

In the specific case of pairs, this can also work to sort *first* by the second element, and then by the first:

```
scala.util.Sorting.stableSort(v)(manifest[(Char, Int)], Ordering.by(_.swap))
```

Answer (score 2):

2.7 and not in place:

```
(Array((2,3), (4,2), (1,5)).toList.sort (_._2 < _._2)).toArray
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `def stableSort[K](a : Seq[K], f : (K, K) => Boolean) : Array[K]` from scala.util.Sorting.
Your comparison function would be something like `_._2 < _._1`

Answer (score 1):

```
val l = List((2, 1), (3, 2), (0, 3))
l sort { case(a, b) => a > b }
```

Comment: Problem is I have an Array :(