# What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?

Tags: scala

I've taken a look at [the list](http://www.scala-lang.org/poll) of surveys taken on [scala-lang.org](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and noticed a curious question: "[Can you name all the uses of “_”?](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5496)". Can you? If yes, please do so here. Explanatory examples are appreciated.

Comment: I read this decent set of slides not long ago: [Scala Dreaded Underscore](http://www.slideshare.net/normation/scala-dreaded)

Answer (score 646):

The ones I can think of are

#### Existential types

```
def foo(l: List[Option[_]]) = ...
```

#### Higher kinded type parameters

```
case class A[K[_],T](a: K[T])
```

#### Ignored variables

```
val _ = 5
```

#### Ignored parameters

```
List(1, 2, 3) foreach { _ => println("Hi") }
```

#### Ignored names of self types

```
trait MySeq { _: Seq[_] => }
```

#### Wildcard patterns

```
Some(5) match { case Some(_) => println("Yes") }
```

#### Wildcard patterns in interpolations

```
"abc" match { case s"a$_c" => }
```

#### Sequence wildcard in patterns

```
C(1, 2, 3) match { case C(vs @ _*) => vs.foreach(f(_)) }
```

#### Wildcard imports

```
import java.util._
```

#### Hiding imports

```
import java.util.{ArrayList => _, _}
```

#### Joining letters to operators

```
def bang_!(x: Int) = 5
```

#### Assignment operators

```
def foo_=(x: Int) { ... }
```

#### Placeholder syntax

```
List(1, 2, 3) map (_ + 2)
```

#### Method values

```
List(1, 2, 3) foreach println _
```

#### Converting call-by-name parameters to functions

```
def toFunction(callByName: => Int): () => Int = callByName _
```

#### Default initializer

```
var x: String = _   // unloved syntax may be eliminated
```

There may be others I have forgotten!

---

Example showing why `foo(_)` and `foo _` are different:

This example [comes from 0__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610736/strange-type-mismatch-when-using-member-access-instead-of-extractor/9610961):

```
trait PlaceholderExample {
  def process[A](f: A => Unit)

  val set: Set[_ => Unit]

  set.foreach(process _) // Error 
  set.foreach(process(_)) // No Error
}
```

In the first case, `process _` represents a method; Scala takes the polymorphic method and attempts to make it monomorphic by filling in the type parameter, but realizes that there is no *type* that can be filled in for `A` that will give the type `(_ => Unit) => ?` (Existential `_` is not a type).

In the second case, `process(_)` is a lambda; when writing a lambda with no explicit argument type, Scala infers the type from the argument that `foreach` expects, and `_ => Unit` *is* a type (whereas just plain `_` isn't), so it can be substituted and inferred.

This may well be the trickiest gotcha in Scala I have ever encountered.

Note that this example compiles in 2.13. Ignore it like it was assigned to underscore.

Comment: I think there are two or three that all fit under underscore usage in pattern matching, but +1 for joining letters to punctuation! :-)

Comment: @Owen I don't think println _ is a partially applied function.  It is another example of placeholder syntax right?  Meaning map(_ + 2) expands to something similar to map(x => x + 2) just as pritnln(_) expands to something similar to map(x => println(x))

Comment: @AndrewCassidy Actually `println _` and `println(_)` are different. You can see this for example in that they handle existential and polymorphic types slightly differently. Will come up with an example in a bit.

Comment: @AndrewCassidy OK I have added an example.

Comment: Ive documented some formal language theory motivations for underscore and tried to show the links of each use with something in Natural Language here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25763401/1586965

Comment: @GiovanniBotta, I guess it should be **var** x: Any = _

Comment: So underscore is basically Scala's wildcard?

Comment: @shinzou It's like a wildcard that stands for many different kinds of wildness. A wild wildcard, if you will.

Comment: lol this language is so trippy... Why does an electrical engineer need to know such a high level language like scala though?

Comment: `val _ = 5` looks really strange.

Comment: I think you forget the one to gives a Seq[T] as Seq.size parameters, Map(Seq((1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)):_*), don t remember the exact name at the moment. Thanks for your sharing, i’ve still many things to learn !

Comment: I'd upvote this answer if each case would have an equal alternative of what it means.

Answer (score 209):

From (my entry) in the [FAQ](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html), which I certainly do not guarantee to be complete (I added two entries just two days ago):

```
import scala._    // Wild card -- all of Scala is imported
import scala.{ Predef => _, _ } // Exception, everything except Predef
def f[M[_]]       // Higher kinded type parameter
def f(m: M[_])    // Existential type
_ + _             // Anonymous function placeholder parameter
m _               // Eta expansion of method into method value
m(_)              // Partial function application
_ => 5            // Discarded parameter
case _ =>         // Wild card pattern -- matches anything
val (a, _) = (1, 2) // same thing
for (_ <- 1 to 10)  // same thing
f(xs: _*)         // Sequence xs is passed as multiple parameters to f(ys: T*)
case Seq(xs @ _*) // Identifier xs is bound to the whole matched sequence
var i: Int = _    // Initialization to the default value
def abc_<>!       // An underscore must separate alphanumerics from symbols on identifiers
t._2              // Part of a method name, such as tuple getters
1_000_000         // Numeric literal separator (Scala 2.13+)
```

This is also part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888944/scala-punctuation-aka-symbols-operators/7890032#7890032).

Comment: May be you can add `var i: Int = _` or the special case of pattern matching `val (a, _) = (1, 2)` or the special case of discarded val `for (_ <- 1 to 10) doIt()`

Comment: And `def f: T; def f_=(t: T)` combo for creating mutable f member.

Comment: Pattern matching is already covered, and `_` on method names is cheating. But, well, ok. I just hope someone else updates the FAQ... :-)

Comment: Maybe you miss this one. vertx.newHttpServer.websocketHandler(_.writeXml(html))

Comment: @angelokh That's anonymous function placeholder parameter, fifth down the list.

Comment: @yarek-t The `for (_ <- 1 to 10)` is _not_ discarded parameter, because `_` is not in the place of a parameter, but of a pattern match. Well, I suppose it could be argued that in the absence of a pattern, it's just a parameter, so it could be thought of like that as well.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Apoligies. I saw it as a for comprehension, but of course its not a flatMap. `_` is so overloaded, it trips me up regularly

Comment: @YarekT It can be `flatmap`, `map` or `foreach`, but that's not the point. You can do stuff like this: `for ((a,b) <- listOfPairs) yield a+b`, and that becomes `listOfPairs.map { case (a,b) => a + b }`, which is why I classified it as pattern matching instead of ignored parameter.

Comment: You are right, it is a pattern match underneath, sort of counter-intuitive as practically you don't have that parameter to use. (could `x@_ <- ...` be valid here?) For comprehensions also can use `=`: `for { ...; _ = foo()}`, which throws me off, Thats a proper discarded value isn't it.

Comment: @YarekT `x@_ <- ...`? Maybe you meant `x @ _*`? I think `_*` can only be used inside `unapplySeq` matchers. As for the second, no, because assignment is _also_ a pattern match. You can do `val Some(a) = someOption`, for example.

Comment: I think explanatory code examples with results of commands would be useful

Answer (score 96):

An excellent explanation of the uses of the underscore is *[Scala _ [underscore] magic](http://ananthakumaran.in/2010/03/29/scala-underscore-magic.html)*.

Examples:

```
 def matchTest(x: Int): String = x match {
     case 1 => "one"
     case 2 => "two"
     case _ => "anything other than one and two"
 }

 expr match {
     case List(1,_,_) => " a list with three element and the first element is 1"
     case List(_*)  => " a list with zero or more elements "
     case Map[_,_] => " matches a map with any key type and any value type "
     case _ =>
 }

 List(1,2,3,4,5).foreach(print(_))
 // Doing the same without underscore: 
 List(1,2,3,4,5).foreach( a => print(a))
```

In Scala, `_` acts similar to `*` in Java while importing packages.

```
// Imports all the classes in the package matching
import scala.util.matching._

// Imports all the members of the object Fun (static import in Java).
import com.test.Fun._

// Imports all the members of the object Fun but renames Foo to Bar
import com.test.Fun.{ Foo => Bar , _ }

// Imports all the members except Foo. To exclude a member rename it to _
import com.test.Fun.{ Foo => _ , _ }
```

In Scala, a getter and setter will be implicitly defined for all non-private vars in a object. The getter name is same as the variable name and `_=` is added for the setter name.

```
class Test {
    private var a = 0
    def age = a
    def age_=(n:Int) = {
            require(n>0)
            a = n
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val t = new Test
t.age = 5
println(t.age)
```

If you try to assign a function to a new variable, the function will be invoked and the result will be assigned to the variable. This confusion occurs due to the optional braces for method invocation. We should use _ after the function name to assign it to another variable.

```
class Test {
    def fun = {
        // Some code
    }
    val funLike = fun _
}
```

Comment: That is a good explanation, but it doesn't even have all of them. It's missing ignored parameters/variables, joining letters and punctuation, existential types, higher kinded types

Comment: in your `List(1,2,3,4,5).foreach(print(_))` it's much more readable to just do `List(1,2,3,4,5).foreach(print)`, you don't even really need the underscore at all, but I guess that's just a matter of style

Comment: how about  "_" works as place holder in Collections with function .map, .flatten, .toList ...... Sometime, it makes me misunderstanding. :(

Answer (score 37):

There is one usage I can see everyone here seems to have forgotten to list...

Rather than doing this:

```
List("foo", "bar", "baz").map(n => n.toUpperCase())
```

You could can simply do this:

```
List("foo", "bar", "baz").map(_.toUpperCase())
```

Comment: so _ here acts as a namespace of all available functions?

Comment: @Crt no, it acts as a shorthand for `n => n`

Comment: isn't this the placeholder syntax mentioned in the top two answers?

Answer (score 15):

Here are some more examples where `_` is used:

```
val nums = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

nums filter (_ % 2 == 0)

nums reduce (_ + _)

nums.exists(_ > 5)

nums.takeWhile(_ < 8)
```

In all above examples one underscore represents an element in the list (for reduce the first underscore represents the accumulator)

Answer (score 14):

Besides the [usages](http://ananthakumaran.in/2010/03/29/scala-underscore-magic.html) that JAiro mentioned, I like this one:

```
def getConnectionProps = {
    ( Config.getHost, Config.getPort, Config.getSommElse, Config.getSommElsePartTwo )
}
```

If someone needs all connection properties, he can do:

```
val ( host, port, sommEsle, someElsePartTwo ) = getConnectionProps
```

If you need just a host and a port, you can do:

```
val ( host, port, _, _ ) = getConnectionProps
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific example that "_" be used:

```
  type StringMatcher = String => (String => Boolean)

  def starts: StringMatcher = (prefix:String) => _ startsWith prefix
```

may be equal to :

```
  def starts: StringMatcher = (prefix:String) => (s)=>s startsWith prefix
```

Applying “_” in some scenarios will automatically convert to “(x$n) => x$n ”

Comment: feel everyone's example is an element of iteration, I think this is more like a low-level syntax sugar, said lambda concise conversion