# Strange type mismatch when using member access instead of extractor

Tags: scala, existential-type, higher-kinded-types

Given a tuple with elements of type `A` and another type parametrised in `A`:

```
trait Writer[-A] { def write(a: A): Unit }
case class Write[A](value: A, writer: Writer[A])
```

And a use site:

```
trait Cache { def store[A](value: A, writer: Writer[A]): Unit }
```

Why does the following work as expected, using the tuple's extractor:

```
def test1(set: Set[Write[_]], cache: Cache): Unit =
  set.foreach {
    case Write(value, writer) => cache.store(value, writer)
  }
```

But the following fails:

```
def test2(set: Set[Write[_]], cache: Cache ): Unit =
  set.foreach { write =>
    cache.store(write.value, write.writer)
  }
```

with error message

```
 found   : Writer[_$1] where type _$1
 required: Writer[Any]
             cache.store(write.value, write.writer)
                                        ^
```

Can I fix the second form (`test2`) to compile properly?

**EDIT**

Departing from the ideas by Owen I tried out if I can make it work without pattern matching at all (which is what I wanted in the first place). Here are two more strange cases, one working, the other not:

```
// does not work
def test3(set: Set[Write[_]], cache: Cache): Unit = {
  def process[A](write: Write[A]): Unit =
    cache.store(write.value, write.writer)

  set.foreach(process)
}

// _does work_
def test4(set: Set[Write[_]], cache: Cache): Unit = {
  def process[A](write: Write[A]): Unit =
    cache.store(write.value, write.writer)

  set.foreach(w => process(w))
}
```

Still pretty obscure to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running with `-Xprint:typer` is illuminating here. The problem with `test2` is
that there is an existential type, which appears in two separate places: both
`write.value` and `write.writer` have an existential type, but, crucially, the
compiler has no way of knowing that they have the *same* existentially
quantified type variable. Even though you access them from the same object, the
compiler forgets they came from the same place.

When `test1` is fully typed, you see:

```
def test1(set: Set[Write[_]], cache: Cache) =
    set.foreach(((x0$1: Write[_]) => x0$1 match {
      case (value: _$1, writer: Writer[_$1])Write[_$1]((value @ _), (writer @ _)) =>
          cache.store[_$1](value, writer)
    }));
```

The type variable `_$1` is matched along with the values. Matching the type variable `_$1` binds it in
the scope of the `case`, so it's not existential anymore, and Scala can tell
that `value` and `writer` have the same type parameter.

The solution for `test2` is to not use existentials:

```
def test2[A]( set: Set[ Write[ A ]], cache: Cache ) {
   set.foreach { write =>
      cache.store( write.value, write.writer )
   }
}
```

or to bind the type variable with a match:

```
def test2( set: Set[ Write[ _ ]], cache: Cache ) {
   set.foreach { case write: Write[a] =>
      cache.store( write.value, write.writer )
   }
}
```

**edit**

Let me endeavor to answer the new questions you brought up.

The reason `test3` does not work, is that when you write:

set.foreach( process )

`process`, which is polymorphic, has to be made monomorphic, for two reasons (that I know of):

1. Functions in Scala cannot be polymorphic; only methods can be. `process` as defined as a method; when used as a first-class function, it is a function.
2. The way the compiler does type inference is mostly by taking polymorphic values and unifying them together to make them less polymorphic. Passing an actual polymorphic value as a method argument would require higher-rank types.

The reason that `test4` *does* work is that the function literal:

```
set.foreach( w => process( w ))
```

is actually not a polymorphic function! It takes as its argument an exestentially qualified type; but not a polymorphic type. It then calls the *method* (not the function) `process`, and matches the existential type variable to `process`'s type parameter. Pretty wild, eh?

You could also write:

```
set.foreach( process(_) )
```

which, creating an anonymous function, means the same thing.

Another route you may or may not find appropriate would be to discard
existential types and use type members:

```
trait Writable {
    type A
    val value: A
    val writer: Writer[A]
}

case class Write[T]( value: T, writer: Writer[ T ]) extends Writable {
    type A = T
}

def test2( set: Set[Writable], cache: Cache ) {
    set.foreach { write =>
        cache.store( write.value, write.writer )
    }
}
```

Here Scala is able to see that `write.value` and `write.writer` have the same
type parameter because they have the same path dependent type.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your first solution is not applicable, because each Write will have a different type parameter. Your second solution is viable.

Comment: I still don't really understand what's going on. See my edit to the question. That's why I like to keep the question open for a bit more.