# Compose function with ONLY implicit parameter argument

Tags: scala

Method with ONLY `implicit` parameter

```
scala> def test1 (implicit i:Int )= Option(i)
test1: (implicit i: Int)Option[Int]
```

In trying to convert `test1`  into a `function` as shown below throws following error. I must be missing something obvious here?

```
scala> def test2(implicit i:Int) = test1 _
  <console>:8: error: type mismatch;
   found   : Option[Int]
 required: ? => ?
     def test2(implicit i:Int) = test1 _
```

Comment: So you want to make function that makes an option from implicit i ? Why do you add underscore after test1 call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange type mismatch when using member access instead of extractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610736/strange-type-mismatch-when-using-member-access-instead-of-extractor)

Answer (score 0):

When using implicit parameter you have one in the scope. Like this:

```
object test{
  implicit var i = 10
  def fun(implicit i: Int) = println(i)
}

test.fun
```

And if you want to make an option isntance of something you should use `Some()`

Comment: I think it's more a type inference issue @Haito.

Comment: Yeah, now i can see that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an implicit `Int` in scope when defining `test2`, it's applied to `test1`, so you really end up with `test1(i) _`, which makes no sense to the compiler.

If it did compile, `test2` would return the same function corresponding to `test1` independent of the argument. If that's what you actually want, you can fix it by being more explicit: `test1(_: Int)` or `{ x: Int => test1(x) }` instead of `test1 _`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different possible answers here depending on what it is exactly you are trying to achieve. If you meant `test2` to be a behaviorally identical *method* to `test1` then there is no need to use the underscore (and indeed you cannot!).

```
def test3(implicit i: Int) = test1(i)
```

If you meant `test2` to be a behaviorally identical *function* to `test1`, then you need to do the following:

```
val test4 = test1(_: Int)
```

Note that I am using a `val` instead of a `def` here, because when using the underscore, I am turning `test1` which was originally a method into an instance of a class (specifically one which extends Function2, i.e. a function). Also note that `test4` no longer has implicit parameters as it is a function (and to the best of my knowledge functions cannot have implicit parameters) whereas `test1` was a method.

Why you need to do this as opposed to just `test1 _` turns out to be pretty complex...

**TLDR: Scala is finnicky about the difference between `foo(_)` and `foo _`, methods are different from functions, and implicit resolution takes higher precedence over eta-expansion**

Turning a method into a function object by way of an anonymous function in Scala is known as "eta-expansion." In general eta-expansion comes from the lambda calculus and refers to turning a term into its equivalent anonymous function (e.g. `thing` becomes `x => thing(x)`) or in the language of the lambda calculus, adding an abstraction over a term.

Note that without eta-expansion, programming in Scala would be absolutely torturous because *methods are not functions*. Therefore they cannot be directly passed as arguments to other methods or other functions. Scala tries to convert methods into functions via eta-expansion whenever possible, so as to give the appearance that you can pass methods to other methods.

So why doesn't the following work?

```
val test5 = test1 _ // error: could not find implicit value for parameter i: Int
```

Well let's see what would happen if we tried `test4` without a type signature.

```
val test6 = test1(_) // error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => test1(x$1))
```

Ah ha, different errors!

This is because `test1(_)` and `test1 _` are subtly different things. `test1(_)` is partially applying the method `test1` while `test1 _` is a direction to perform eta-expansion on `test1` *until it is fully applied*.

For example,

```
math.pow(_) // error: not enough arguments for method pow: (x: Double, y: Double)Double.
math.pow _ // this is fine
```

But what about the case where we have just one argument? What's the difference between partial application and eta-expansion of just one abstraction? Not really all that much. One way to view it is that eta-expansion is one way of implementing partial application. Indeed the Scala Spec seems to be silent on the difference between `foo(_)` and `foo _` for a single parameter method. The only difference that matters for us is that the expansion that occurs in `foo(_)` always "binds" tighter than `foo _`, indeed it seems to bind as closely as method application does.

That's why `test1(_)` gives us an error about types. Partial application is treated analogously to normal method application. Because normal method application must always take place before implicit resolution, otherwise we could never replace an implicit value with our own value, partial application takes place before implicit resolution. It just so happens that the way Scala implements partial application is via eta-expansion and therefore we get the expansion into the anonymous function which then complains about the lack of a type for its argument.

My reading of Section 6.26 of the [Scala Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-conversions) suggests that there is an ordering to the resolution of various conversions. In particular it seems to list resolving implicits as coming before eta-expansion. Indeed, for fully-applied eta-expansion, it would seem that this would necessarily be the case since Scala functions cannot have implicit parameters (only its methods can).

Hence, in the case of `test5` as @Alexey says, when we are explicitly telling Scala to eta-expand `test1` with `test1 _`, the implicit resolution takes place first, and then eta-expansion tries to take place, which fails because after implicit resolution Scala's typechecker realizes we have an `Option` not a method.

So that's why we need `test1(_)` over `test1 _`. The final type annotation `test1(_: Int)` is needed because Scala's type inference isn't robust enough to determine that after eta-expanding `test1`, the only possible type you can give to the anonymous function is the same as the type signature for the method. In fact, if we gave the type system enough hints, we can get away with `test1(_)`.

```
val test7: Int => Option[Int] = test1(_) // this works

val test8: Int => Option[Int] = test1 _ // this still doesn't
```