# underscore in expression

Tags: scala, wildcard, scalaz, scalaz7

What does the underscore mean in below snipped. This is fragment of scalaz7 library:

```
trait Apply[F[_]] extends Functor[F] { self =>
  //...
  def ap[A, B](fa: => F[A])(f: => F[A => B]): F[B]
  //...
  def apF[A, B](f: => F[A => B]): F[A] => F[B] = ap(_)(f)   // <----HERE
  //...
}
```

What are the general rules of using that?

Comment: More generally, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala, the underscore in general is a wildcard character. Here specifically, it is a shorthand for a parameter name. So the lambda expression `ap(_)(f)` is equivalent to `x => ap(x)(f)`.

You can use `_` as shorthand for the parameter(s) of an anonymous function if each parameter is used only once, and they are used in the order of their declaration.