# Force grouping of ascription on underscore in scala

Tags: scala, scala-placeholder-syntax, ascription

I am trying to do:

`MyObject.myMethod(_:MyType.myAttribute)`

This fails with

`type myAttribute is not a member of object MyObject`

which is correct. The problem is that I want to call `myMethod` on `myAttribute` of `_:MyType`, not ascribe `MyType:myAttribute` to `_`. Can I somehow group the type ascription `_:MyType`? `(_:MyType).myAttribute` returns type `MyType => classOf(myAttribute)`, which is not what I want.

Edit: I changed the title and text of this post to no longer refer to this as the associativity of the dot, which I believe was not correct.

Comment: Someone with enough reputation to create new tags should replace `casting` with `ascription` or `ascribe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to create function `(m: MyType) => MyObject.myMethod(m.myAttribute)` using [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001065/406435)?

If so, the problem is that `MyObject.myMethod((_:MyType).myAttribute)` means `MyObject.myMethod((m:MyType) => m.myAttribute)`.

You can use infix notation:

```
MyObject myMethod (_:MyType).myAttribute
```

Proof it works:

```
scala> case class MyType(myAttribute: Int)
defined class MyType

scala> object MyObject {
     |   def myMethod(a: Int) = a.toString
     | }
defined module MyObject

scala> MyObject myMethod (_:MyType).myAttribute
res0: MyType => java.lang.String = <function1>

scala> res0(MyType(1))
res1: java.lang.String = 1

scala> MyObject myMethod (MyType(1))
<console>:1: error: type mismatch;
 found   : MyType
 required: Int
              MyObject myMethod (_:MyType)
                                  ^
```

Comment: Neato.  It works because while func args are Exprs, InfixExprs are not. (Responding to prev comment.)

Comment: This does not work for what I am trying to do. This calls `myMethod` on `_:Mytpe`; this does not call `myMethod` on `_:MyType`'s `myAttribute`. This has the same effect as `(myMethod(_:MyType)).myAttribute)`

Comment: @taz It's not true. Result of `myMethod` don't have `myAttribute` member. I've added proof to my answer.

Comment: No, where you got `res0: MyType => java.lang.String = <function1>`, in your example I would be expecting a `String`.

Comment: Maybe @taz should post his code. I really had no idea what you were going for.

Comment: `TitleController get (_:Media) titleID` gives me `type mismatch: found: Media; required: Int`. I am trying to call `get` on the `titleID` attribute of `_:Media`. `titleID` is an `Int`.

Comment: @taz Use `TitleController get (_:Media).titleID` as in my answer.

Comment: That changed things. I might be on the way here. I'm getting a different error from the longer expression: `((TitleController get (_:Media).titleID):Option[Title]).exists(...)` gives `found: Media => Option[Title]; required: Option[Title]`. `get` returns `Option[Title]`. If I use `TitleController.get` I get the exact same error as before.

Comment: @taz: It's a different question.

Comment: @taz: Try `TitleController get (_:Media).titleID exists(...)`.

Comment: @senia That compiled! Thanks! I realize that was a different question but I figured you probably knew the answer. Hopefully it works in testing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this illustrates or answers your question, but it's true.

My guess is that you expected your a.b(_.i) to be an anon func after you add an ascription (to type the parameter).

But the subexpr foils you by `there is no other expression of syntactic category Expr which is properly contained in e and which itself properly contains u.` (SLS 6.23)

Also, you can use `scalac -Xprint:parser` to see how it's taken.

```
object Foo {
  def m(k: Int) = 7 * k
}
class Bar {
  val i = 5
  val What = i
}
object Bar {
  type What = Int
}

object Test extends App {
  Foo.m(_:Bar.What)
  // this is not anon func placeholder syntax...
  //Foo.m((_:Bar).What)  // _ is in a subexpr
  //Foo.m(_.i)
  // ...for this
  val f = (x: Bar) => Foo.m(x.i)
  // InfixExpr is ok
  val g = Foo m (_: Bar).i
  val b = new Bar
  println(f(b))
  println(g(b))
}
```

Contrast, to illustrate what is being restricted:

```
scala> val f: (Int,Int)=>Int = _+_
f: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val g: Int=>Int = if (_ > 0) 1 else 2
<console>:7: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$greater(0))
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have described in my original post. I have in place the `(x: Bar) => Foo.m(x.i)` construct. I understand why `(_:Bar.What)` doesn't work. Is there no way to associate the `What` to the entire `_:Bar`? This seems like an accidental limitation of the syntax; can I not use an associativity operator somehow to cause the `Bar` to apply to the `_` and not the `What`?

Answer (score 0):

```
List(1,2,3).map((i: Int) => i * i)
```

**EDIT**

```
List(1,2,3).map((_: Int).unary_-)
```

**EDIT 2**

```
implicit class MyAttribute(i: Int) { def myMethod() = i * i }
List(1,2,3).map((_: Int).myMethod.unary_-)
```

**Explanation**

I used implicit class (Scala-2.10) to add myMethod on Int, after that unary "-" operation executed on result. You could add something like `def wrap: MyAttribute` to `MyAttribute`, and use it like `(_: Int).wrap.method1.method2.method3.result.abs`, for example.

Comment: I am aware of how to accomplish my goal using `=>`; I am asking specifically how to accomplish this using the underscore. The problem is not that the underscore can't be properly ascribed; the problem is the associativity of the ascription. Your example does not address this unless I missed something.

Comment: I see that you edited your answer but I don't understand this at all. Can you provide some explanation?