# why scala placeholder doesn't work

Tags: scala

Hello everybody I'm trying to understand the symbol "_" in scala, it looks like a wildcard but I did not understand why in the given scenario.

```
   var l = List("a","b" ,"c")
   // Works "s" works as a variable.
   l.foreach( s =>
     if(s=="a"){
       print(s)
     }
   )

   // Works _ takes the place of "s"
   l.foreach(
     print(_)
   )

  //So the doubt is whether "_" is a wildcard that does not work well.

  l.foreach(
    if(_=="a"){
      print(_)
    }
  )
```

"_" should act like the variable `s`, but why it doesn't?

Comment: I'm about 99.8973% sure that `_` works just fine.  It's how you're using it, or what you're expecting of it, that is the issue.

Comment: You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903 among other things.  You're mixing uses of underscores, I think.  (Also, underscore can be used exactly once per variable; a second underscore tries to bind to a second variable, not the first one a second time.  So: `foreach{ _ + 1 }` is okay, `foreach{ _ * _ }` is not.  If you need to refer to the same variable multiple times, name it: `foreach{ x => x * x }`).)

Answer (score 12):

Wildcards in anonymous functions are expanded in a way that n-th _ is treated as n-th argument. The way you're using it makes scala compiler think you're actually have something like

```
l.foreach((x,y) =>
    if(x=="a"){
      print(y)
    }
)
```

Which is obviously invalid.

Comment: It parses to `l.foreach({ if ((x) => x == "a") { (y) => print(y) } })`, though.