# Scala understanding right associative operand

Tags: scala, syntax, operand

i am learning scala ( like it! ) but there is something i dont understand. 
i read about right associative operand by method names ending with ":". Easy to understand but i wanted to define my own right associative function named add3To:.

I have a syntaxerror and dont know why:

```
case class MyInt(x : Int) {
   def add3 = x+3

   def add3To:= x+3 // dont understand whats wrong here
}

val myInt = MyInt(4)
println(myInt add3)  // working 
println(add3To myInt)  // not working
```

Maybe ( i am pretty sure) i did a dumb mistake! But i dont see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place an [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001065/406435) between letters and punctuation characters in name. `add3To_:`, not `add3To:`.

Method should accept a single parameter: `addTo_:(i: Int)`.

```
scala> case class MyInt(x : Int) {
     |    def addTo_:(i: Int): Int = x+i
     | }
defined class MyInt

scala> val myInt = MyInt(4)
myInt: MyInt = MyInt(4)

scala> 3 addTo_: myInt
res0: Int = 7
```

Comment: thank you. does it mean i cant define a method which is right associative and only takes 1 operand ( add3to myInt). Your method i also cant call " 3 addTo myInt"?

Comment: @chrisf: 1) You could just define `def add3To(mi: MyInt) = i.x+3` and call it as `add3To(myInt)`. 2) You could add method `addTo(mi: MyInt)` to `Int` - see [`implicit class`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html).