# Syntax and meaning of a Scala/Play! code sample

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following **Scala/Play!** code:

```
case class Tweet(from: String, text: String)

implicit val tweetReads = (
 (JsPath \ "from_user_name").read[String] ~
 (JsPath \ "text").read[String]) (Tweet.apply _)
```

I have **several questions regarding the syntax and meaning of the above code**:

- On what class/object is the `~` method invoked on?
- What is the class/type of the argument to `Tweet.apply`?

**edit 1**: full source code:

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.util._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Tweet(from: String, text: String)

object Tweet {

  implicit val tweetReads = (
      (JsPath \ "from_user_name").read[String] ~
      (JsPath \ "text").read[String])(Tweet.apply _)

  implicit val tweetWrites = (
    (JsPath \ "from").write[String] ~
    (JsPath \ "text").write[String])(unlift(Tweet.unapply))
}
```

Comment: Please add `play` version and imports.

Comment: I use Play! 2.2.1. I have updated my post with the full source code for the model.

Comment: See docs page for [JSON Reads/Writes/Format Combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) v2.8.x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step by step:

Method `\` on object JsPath

```
val path1: JsPath = JsPath \ "from_user_name"
val path2: JsPath = JsPath \ "text"
```

Method `read` on object of type `JsPath`

```
val reads1: Reads[String] = path1.read[String]
val reads2: Reads[String] = path2.read[String]
```

There is no method `~` in `Reads`, but there is such method in `FunctionalBuilderOps` and there is an implicit conversion from `M[T]` to `FunctionalBuilderOps[M[_], T]` in [`play.api.libs.functional.syntax`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.1/framework/src/play-functional/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/syntax/package.scala#L18) - `toFunctionalBuilderOps`.

```
val reads1FunctionalBuilderOps: FunctionalBuilderOps[Reads, String] =
  toFunctionalBuilderOps(reads1)

val canBuild2: CanBuild2[String, String] = reads1FunctionalBuilderOps.~(reads2)
```

`Tweet.apply _` is a scala syntax to create a `FunctionN` using method with `N` arguments:

```
val func: (String, String) => Tweet = Tweet.apply _
```

There is an `apply` method in `CanBuild2[A, B]`. It accepts `(A, B) => C` and returns `Reads[C]` (in this case):

```
implicit val tweetReads: Reads[Tweet] = canBuild2.apply(func)
```

Actually there are also implicit parameters in `JsPath#read`, `toFunctionalBuilderOps` and `CanBuild2#apply` methods. With that parameters:

```
val reads1: Reads[String] = path1.read[String](Reads.StringReads)

...
val reads1FunctionalBuilderOps: FunctionalBuilderOps[Reads, String] =
  toFunctionalBuilderOps(reads1)(
    functionalCanBuildApplicative(
      Reads.applicative(JsResult.applicativeJsResult)))

...
implicit val tweetReads: Reads[Tweet] =
  canBuild2.apply(func)(functorReads)
```

Comment: Hi Senia! Thanks for this detailed reply. I am in the process of studying your reply. I will come up with questions. Bear with me...

Comment: Can you please confirm that `Tweet.apply _` is an invocation of apply? Also what is the `_` placeholder standing for?

Comment: I am confused with this `Tweet.apply _`... Why is there only one argument to apply (i.e. _)?

Comment: @balteo: here `Tweet.apply _` is special syntax for something like  `(a, b) => Tweet.apply(a, b)`. You need a function of type `(A1, A2, ... AN) => R` and you have a method `(A1, A2, ... AN)R`. `method _` is a syntax to create new function (object of type `FunctionN`) using method.

Comment: @balteo: it's not `one argument`. `Tweet.apply(_)` means `one argument`, but `Tweet.apply _` means `all arguments`.

Comment: Thanks.... I am also looking for official documentation/references about `val func: (String, String) => Tweet = Tweet.apply _` I cannot seem to find anything about this construct/syntax in my books. Can you please kindly provide a link?

Comment: Also in `Tweet.apply _`, how is **this** specific usage of the underscore called in scala parlance?

Comment: @balteo: see [The Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) **6.7 Method Values**.

Comment: @balteo: See also [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)

Comment: In this line https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9206bea8c9c88acdc6786ebb2554f081396e8f6a/framework/src/play-functional/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/syntax/package.scala#L21, from where does the first `implicit` (fcb) argument come? `implicit def toFunctionalBuilderOps[M[_], A](a: M[A])(implicit fcb: FunctionalCanBuild[M]) ...`

Comment: @KevinMeredith: [next method (line 23)](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9206bea8c9c88acdc6786ebb2554f081396e8f6a/framework/src/play-functional/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/syntax/package.scala#L23)

Comment: Ah, so you knew that `OFormat[A]` is-a `Applicative[A]`? Or you used `REPL` to identify the implicit?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: there is only 5 imports in question, so one can find all implicits in that imports and companion objects. I don't need REPL for this. But with `reify` one can get all implicits in REPL.

Comment: @senia, thanks. So for `Format.scala`, you know that line 20 (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9206bea8c9c88acdc6786ebb2554f081396e8f6a/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Format.scala?source=cc#L20) resolves its `rcb` and `wcb` by looking at the implicits in line 18(https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9206bea8c9c88acdc6786ebb2554f081396e8f6a/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Format.scala?source=cc#L18)?

Answer (score 2):

I would just add that this is called applicative syntax (for applicative functors). It can be seen for example in [scala parser combinator library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers)

If you want to know how to use it with json try to read [this](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators). Another example of applicative functors in play framework is [form handling](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms). Or you can try to read about scalaz Validation.