# What is the use cases of Ignored Variable syntax in Scala?

Tags: scala

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001065/1586965 we can do this in Scala:

```
val _ = 5
```

Now I understand the point of ignored parameters in lambda expressions, but I cannot really imagine examples where I would ever want to declare a variable that by definition I cannot reference.  The only example I can think of is being lazy about naming *implicit* values, e.g.

```
implicit val _: MyNumeric = ...
...
class A[T : MyNumeric] {
...
```

Is this the only use case? Am I missing something?

If it is the only use case, shouldn't the compiler/IDE give a warning/hint when the `val` is *not* implicit as it is utterly pointless?

**Clarification**

By variable/value I mean a *single* one, not one that is part of an extraction declaration.

Comment: Your clarify says you don't mean patterns, but the argument at the end of this ticket is that it's a pattern. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7691  I think it's a name, not a pattern, and would require special spec; but still interesting.

Comment: Someone answered with for-comps like here (for uncontrived example): https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/Responder.scala#L44  and similarly `for (i <- g; _ = v)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It uses a value.

```
$ scala -Ywarn-value-discard
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_11).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def f() = { println("I ran.") ; 42 }
f: ()Int

scala> def g(): Unit = { f() }
<console>:8: warning: discarded non-Unit value
       def g(): Unit = { f() }
                          ^
g: ()Unit

scala> def g(): Unit = { val _ = f() }
g: ()Unit

scala> g
I ran.

scala>
```

To verify, it also doesn't warn under `-Ywarn-unused`.

Comment: Assignments always evaluate to `Unit` in Scala. You get the exact same result if you use `val foo` instead of `val _`, no?

Comment: @JörgWMittag The block still gets unit value inserted at the end as a result expression, but with the assignment, you're not discarding a value; with underscore, you haven't racked your brain to invent an identifier. A stretch to call this a use case.

Answer (score 18):

I don't think that this is a feature at all. In any case, it is **not** an "ignored variable".
By which I mean that if `val _ = 5` really introduced an unnamed value, then you could declare as many as you want in the same single scope.
Not so:

```
scala> object Test {
     |   val _ = 5
     |   val _ = 7
     | }
<console>:9: error: _ is already defined as value _
         val _ = 7
         ^
```

From the error message it seems clear that what really happens is that the value is actually named `_` 
(which I'd call a quirk of the compiler that should be fixed). We can verify this:

```
scala> object Test {
     |   val _ = 5
     |   def test() { println( `_` ) } // This compiles fine
     | }
defined object Test

scala> Test.test()
5
```

As for the possible use of preventing a value discarding warning (as shown in som-snytt's answer), I'much prefer to simply return an explicit `Unit`. 
This looks less convoluted and is even shorter:

```
def g(): Unit = { f(); () }
```

as opposed to:

```
def g(): Unit = { val _ = f() }
```

Comment: Hmm, yes appears its a quirk, not a feature, but I like it and prefer the `val _ = f()` as its only one line. I would never put two lines onto 1 by using semicilons.

Comment: I much prefer this answer

Comment: The fix you requested is in 2.13, so `val _` does not introduce a variable; underscore in backticks still works. The usage `implicit val _` is (temporarily?) broken.

Answer (score 6):

The other use case (that I can think of) is related to extraction (and is called out under "Wildcard patterns" in [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001065/1586965)):

```
val getCartesianPoint = () => (1, 2, 3)
// We don't care about the z axis, so we assign it to _
val (x, y, _) = getCartesianPoint()

val regex = "(.*?)|(.*?)|?.*".r
// Really, any unapply or unapplySeq example will do
val regex(_, secondValue) = "some|delimited|value|set"
```

Comment: Correct, but accepting the other answer as it more closly fits my question. Im going to add a clarification to my question.