# Scala underscore explanation

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tuples

Have a look at these scala snippets:
if we have something like this:

```
List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map (x => (x.size))
```

we can shorten it to:

```
List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map ((_.size))
```

but, if we have something like this:

```
List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map (x => (x.size, x.size))
```

why can't we shorten it to:

```
List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map ((_.size, _.size))
```

?

Comment: Interesting question, i'll stay around here to check the answer

Answer (score 5):

An amount of placeholders should be equals amount of function parameters. In your case `map` has 1 parameter that's why you can't use two placeholders.

Comment: Please, give me an example where I could end up with `map ((_.size, _.size))` on the right side of the expression.

Comment: @GA1 You can't use 2 placeholders with `map` method. Example of usage of 2 placeholders `List(1,2,3,4).reduce(_ + _)` - sum list elements.

Comment: Anyway, I really enjoyed the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763400/motivation-for-scala-underscore-in-terms-of-formal-language-theory-and-good-styl
Especially the part with a reference to linguistics. I still don't understand why the compiler does not allow:
`List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map ((_.size, _.size))`
What is the underlying principle for it? What "danger" would this feature bring along?

Comment: @GA1 What would `List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map ((_.size, _.size))` do? `map` takes an one operand of type `List[Int]`.

Comment: I would like it to return the same result as:
`List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map (x => (x.size, x.size))`

Comment: @GA1 There isn't a way to do that in Scala. It's not do to "danger"; it's due to how _ works for function shorthand. An underscore can only be used once in the body per parameter. To get the equivalent of (_.size, _.size) you have to use the full function signature or map to _.size and transform the resulting list into tuples with duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2):

Because `List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map ((_.size, _.size))` has a different meaning, namely

```
List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5)) map ((x => x.size, y => y.size))
```

(you can see this from the error message). This obviously doesn't compile, because `map` doesn't accept a tuple of two functions.