# Scala inference on _

Tags: scala, type-inference

I'm a newbie to scala(fxnl programming), though I put _ in context in a few places like the below

```
list.map(_ * 1)
```

I couldn't completely understand this statement

```
val story = (catch _) andThen (eat _)
```

though I can infer from the calling

```
story(new Cat, new Bird)
```

that underscore serves as placeholders to the the argument positions, I want to understand the concept behind it.

Comment: Go through this answer to get a decent idea on use of underscore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Comment: Thank you found this as while searching http://www.slideshare.net/normation/scala-dreaded

Answer (score 4):

Statement

```
val story = (catch _) andThen (eat _)
```

is incorrect - because catch is keyword.

But this is correct:

```
scala> def caught(x:Int) = x + 8
caught: (x: Int)Int

scala> def eat(x:Int) = x + 3
eat: (x: Int)Int

scala> val story = (caught _) andThen (eat _) // story is function.
story: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> story(90) // You put 90 - parameter for caught (first _). It returns 90 + 8 and put it to eat (second _). eat function return 98 + 3
res0: Int = 101
```