# using scala.js method as callback

Tags: scala.js

I am loading google map in async way ,

```
@JSExport("sample")
 object Sample {

  def loadScript = {
    val script = document.createElement("script").asInstanceOf[HTMLScriptElement]
    script.`type` = "text/javascript"
    //case 1
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=sample().initialize"
    // case 2
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=sample.initialize"
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }

  @JSExport
  def initialize() :Unit  = {
     println(" map loaded successfully")
  }
}
```

In case 1 google sending response - 400(bad request)

In case 2 i am getting undefined function ( window.sample.initialize())

i can define a javascript function ,inside that function i can call sample().initialize() , but is there any cleaner way ?

Comment: IMHO case 1 should be right. Are you sure this is not just a URL encoding problem?

Comment: no URL encoding issues,:host:maps.googleapis.com
:method:GET
:path:/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=sample().initialize

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. FYI I filed an issue for this: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Scala.js' dynamic API to create the JavaScript function on the top-level. The advantage over @gzm0's solution is that it's less hacky, and requires less boilerplate.

```
object Sample {
  def loadScript = {
    val script = document.createElement("script").asInstanceOf[HTMLScriptElement]
    script.`type` = "text/javascript"
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=initializeSample"
    document.body.appendChild(script)

    js.Dynamic.global.initializeSample = initialize _
  }

  private def initialize(): Unit =
    println("map loaded successfully")
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton man it solved my other issue too :) ,btw  what is that _ ?

Comment: It converts the method into a Function. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacky answer, but potentially useful as a workaround.

Instead of giving the Google API something corresponding to a Scala.js function, you can give it the module initializer directly:

```
object Sample {
  def loadScript = {
    val script = document.createElement("script").asInstanceOf[HTMLScriptElement]
    script.`type` = "text/javascript"
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=initializeSample"
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }
}

@JSExport("initializeSample")
object Initializer {
  println(" map loaded successfully")
}
```

Comment: thank you ,its definitely  a good work around than creating javascript function.