# export function to global scope in scalajs

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

Question about scalajs and javascript.

How to mark a function to be purely exported to global scope?

Given scala object in top level package

```
@JSExport
object Foo{
 def apply(a: Int, b: Int): String = "bar"+a+b
}
```

I would like to compile this scala code into javascript and have this function named `Foo` in global scope. In other words I would like to have a javascript similar to this:

```
function Foo(a,b) {
    return 'bar'+a+b;
}
```

Is it possible using scalajs?

I am writing component in javascript, which will be referenced from third party API which can not be influenced by me. This is why I simply need to follow their rules and provide javascript functions in global scope.

Comment: Hmm -- unusual request.  How does the API work?  It's expecting you to pass the *name* of a function defined in global scope, or something like that?

Comment: API requires to define script with functions in global scope with specific names, like for example ```function anything() {...}``` which will be called whenever any event occurs. See https://docs.cycling74.com/max7/vignettes/jsbasic for more details.

Comment: Actually, this is a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440235/using-scala-js-method-as-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is now Top Level Exports, as documented under the now-closed issue [#1381](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1381) - to use this feature, tag a function in an object with `@JSExportTopLevel`.

```
object A {
  @JSExportTopLevel("foo")
  def foo(x: Int): Int = x + 1
}
```

`<Foo will be available from JavaScript's global namespace>`

(See https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/export-to-javascript.html for the official documentation, under "Exporting top-level methods".)

Comment: Just a note: **your function has to be inside `object` level not inside `main` or other function.**

Answer (score 1):

You currently cannot do this without executing some code. But you can have setup code that assigns it:

```
import scala.scalajs.js

object App extends js.JSApp {
  def main(): Unit = {
    js.Dynamic.global.anything = // your js.FunctionN

  }
}
```

There is an issue open ([#1381](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1381)) to have language support for this.