# Apache-Spark : What is map(_._2) shorthand for?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I read a project's source code, found:

```
val sampleMBR = inputMBR.map(_._2).sample
```

`inputMBR` is a tuple.

the function `map`'s definition is :

```
map[U classTag](f:T=>U):RDD[U]
```

it seems that `map(_._2)` is the shorthand for `map(x => (x._2))`.

Anyone can tell me rules of those shorthand ?

Answer (score 22):

The _ syntax can be a bit confusing. When _ is used on its own it represents an argument in the anonymous function. So if we working on pairs:
`map(_._2 + _._2)` would be shorthand for `map(x, y => x._2 + y._2)`. When _ is used as part of a function name (or value name) it has no special meaning. In this case `x._2` returns the second element of a tuple (assuming x is a tuple).

Answer (score 18):

collection.map(_._2) emits a second component of the tuple. Example from pure Scala (Spark RDDs work the same way):

```
scala> val zipped = (1 to 10).zip('a' to 'j')
zipped: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Char)] = Vector((1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d), (5,e), (6,f), (7,g), (8,h), (9,i), (10,j))

scala> val justLetters = zipped.map(_._2)
justLetters: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
```

Answer (score 10):

Two underscores in '`_._2`' are different.

First '`_`' is for **placeholder** of anonymous function; Second '`_2`' is **member** of case class `Tuple`.

Something like:

> case class Tuple3 (**_1**: T1, **_2**: T2, **_3**: T3) 
>   {...}

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutions.

First the `underscore` here is as **placeholder**.

> To make a function literal even more concise, you can use underscores
>   as placeholders for one or more parameters, so long as each parameter
>   appears only one time within the function literal.

See more about `underscore` in Scala at [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala).

Answer (score 0):

The first '_' is referring what is mapped to and since what is mapped to is a tuple you might call any function within the tuple and one of the method is '_2' so what below tells us transform input into it's second attribute.