# What does '_._2' mean in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is a snippet of code in Spark/Scala:

```
 rdd.sortBy(_._2)
```

What does `_._2` mean here?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246440/apache-spark-what-is-map-2-shorthand-for

Comment: this means the second value of each tuple.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala `_2` is shorthand for accessing second [tuple](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-tuple-examples-syntax) element.

```
val myTuple = ("first", "second")
myTuple._1 // "first"
myTuple._2 // "second"
```

In your case all tuples in `rdd` will be sorted by second element.
For example:

```
val tuples = Vector(("first", "b"),("second", "c"),("third", "a"))
tuples.sortBy(_._2) //Vector((third,a), (first,b), (second,c))
```