# Why do one of these split & filter work but not the other?

Tags: scala, filter

```
val c = s.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")).filter(x =>  
  x.contains("worcester") || x.contains("energy"))
```

Works

But this does not

```
val c = s.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")).filter(_.contains("worcester") || 
  _.contains("energy"))
```

I have not understood it clearly why the latter does not work - may be I have a flaw in my fundamentals

Any help would be very appreciated
thanks
Sumit

Answer (score 5):

Using underscore like this is known as *placeholder* syntax.  So, something like `_.contains("x")` is equivalent to `x => x.contains("x")`.  You can only use each parameter once when using the placeholder syntax.   Using multiple placeholders denotes multiple parameters of the anonymous function (which are then used in order of the underscores).  So, when you write:

```
o.filter(_.contains("worcester") || _.contains("energy"))
```

It would theoretically be equivalent to

```
o.filter((x, y) => x.contains("worcester") || y.contains("energy"))
```

Which doesn't type check, since `filter` expects a parameter of type `Array[String] => Boolean`.

Multiple placeholders are common when using the `reduce` variants.  For example, a factorial can be computed as `(1 to n).reduce(_ * _)`.  This works because `reduce` expects a parameter of type `(Int, Int) => Int`, so `_ * _`, which is equivalent to `(x, y) => x * y` fits the expected type.

It's important to note that the placeholder syntax applies to the smallest possible scope.  So, for example, `f(g(_))` is equivalent to `f(x => g(x))`, and not `x => f(g(x))`, which is a common mistake.

You can find a comprehensive list of the use of underscore in Scala [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala), and a little bit more about the placeholder syntax [here](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/quick-explanation-of-scalas-syntax).