# Scala: (_) in the SQLContext.scala of SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The `Spark` version is **1.3.0**.

The source code from the `SQLContext.scala` (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala):

```
 @transient
  protected[sql] val ddlParser = new DDLParser(sqlParser.apply(_))

  @transient
  protected[sql] val sqlParser = {
    val fallback = new catalyst.SqlParser
    new SparkSQLParser(fallback(_))
  }

  protected[sql] def parseSql(sql: String): LogicalPlan = {
    ddlParser(sql, false).getOrElse(sqlParser(sql))
  }
```

I cannot really understand the code above.

- how does the `sqlParser.apply(_)` work ?

what is **(_)** on earth? **DDLParser**'s constructor needs a parameter `parseQuery: String => LogicalPlan`, but the return type of `sqlParser.apply` is `LogicalPlan`.

- similarly, `fallback(_)` is also a `apply` call, how does **(_)** work?

Answer (score 1):

The underscore in this case denotes a *partial function application*, which is one way to convert a method type into a function type.  So when you write `sqlParser.apply(_)`, it is equivalent to `x => sqlParser.apply(x)`.  Since the `DDLParser` constructor needs an argument of type `String => LogicalPlan`, and `sqlParser.apply` returns a `LogicalPlan`, the compiler can deduce that `x` here is actually a `String`, and so `sqlParser.apply(_)` is of type `String => LogicalPlan`.

You have many options here.  The following would be equivalent under most circumstances:

```
new DDLParser(x => sqlParser.apply(x))
new DDLParser(x => sqlParser(x))
new DDLParser(sqlParser.apply(_))
new DDLParser(sqlParser.apply _)
new DDLParser(sqlParser(_))
new DDLParser(sqlParser _)
new DDLParser(sqlParser.apply)
new DDLParser(sqlParser)
```

You can read more about the difference between methods types and function types [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).

Another, closely related way of turning a method type into a function type is called *eta expansion*, which is used interchangeably in certain contexts.  Read about partial function application, eta expansion, and all the other uses of underscore in Scala [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala).

Comment: what confuses me is that : `val ddlParser = new DDLParser(sqlParser.apply(_))`, when I define such a `ddlParser`, I didn't pass any `x`(String type) to it. How does it do initialization work?

Comment: The constructor of `DDLParser` needs an argument of type `String => LogicalPlan`.  The constructor doesn't need a `String`, but a function that that in a `String` and returns a `LogicalPlan`.  And `sqlParser.apply(_)` returns exactly that type.