# Converting to Json

Tags: json, scala, gson

I have a question about toJson function in google.Gson library.

I read online [here](https://github.com/databricks/reference-apps/blob/master/twitter_classifier/scala/src/main/scala/com/databricks/apps/twitter_classifier/Collect.scala) that I can use it like this toJson(_) what does the underscore sign mean? In the documentation the parameter represents the target type, can you please explain more about what should I pass if I just want to convert log data to Json?

Here's the code I'm asking about:

```
  private var gson = new Gson()
 val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Utils.getAuth)
      .map(gson.toJson(_))
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: I did please check it

Comment: That is actually Scala code, not Java. This answer explains the underscore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Comment: So I assume it refers to an ignored parameter ?

Comment: it's more "apply gson.toJson to TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Utils.getAuth)"... in that case '_' stand for "what you are mapping"

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Scala uses underscore (_) as a wildcard for pattern matching.  In your example it matches anything received from map and inserts it as the argument of gson.toJson().

Answer (score -1):

Gson has desined to make all the Json mess extremely easy.

Anyway, I have used Gson in java on android and it's look like this:

```
static public <T extends JsonAble> T getJson(Context context, Class<T> jsonClass){
    String strClassName = jsonClass.getSimpleName();
    String strJson = getTextFromFile(context, strClassName);
    T objReturn = gsnEncoder.fromJson(strJson, jsonClass);
    return objReturn;
}
```

As you can see, you only need to spesific the object and Gson will do the magic.

EDIT: I have posted fromJson instead toJson), the idea is same, give me a second to fix it.

```
static public <T extends JsonAble> boolean setObject(Context context, T Obj)  {
    boolean IsSucceed = false;
    String strClassName = Obj.getClass().getSimpleName();

    try {
        String strObj =  DL.gsnEncoder.toJson(Obj);
        IsSucceed = DL.setTextToFile(context, strClassName, strObj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return IsSucceed;
}
```

Comment: This explains how to use getJson()/toJson() in Java, but it doesn't explain the meaning of the _ character in scala.

Comment: @M4n Look at the comment on the question, the question about the underscore has already answered. I just explained how to use Json (The second question).