# How to understand this Scala function call

Tags: scala

I am Scala beginner. Below Scala code runs well, but I cannot understand it. Log shows, line 19 finally run to line 12. How could it be?

```
object TestClassDef {
  class Person {
    private var _age = 0
    def age:Int = _age
    def age_=(newAge: Int) = {
      _age = newAge
      println("age changed to " + _age)       // line 12
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var p = new Person()
//    p.age_=(25)
    p.age = 26                                // line 19
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, you're surprised that the method is called when you assign the value on line 19. This is because the _= (at the end of the age function with an Int parameter) means that it's an assignment operator (also see [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)) so it does make sense that it's called when you simply type p.age = 26.

Answer (score 1):

This is mutator

```
def age_=(newAge: Int) = {
  _age = newAge
  println("age changed to " + _age)   
}
```

So the call

```
 p.age = 26
```

is converted by compiler to

```
 p.age_=(26)
```

which makes call to mutator.

Mutator naming conventions from http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html

For mutators, the name of the method should be the name of the property with “_=” appended. As long as a corresponding accessor with that particular property name is defined on the enclosing type, this convention will enable a call-site mutation syntax which mirrors assignment. Note that this is not just a convention but a requirement of the language.

Also to see what compiler is creating pass -Xprint:typer to the Scala compiler. For reference the above code with this parameter generates:

```
package <empty> {
  object TestClassDef extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): TestClassDef.type = {
      TestClassDef.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    class Person extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>(): TestClassDef.Person = {
        Person.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      private[this] var _age: Int = 0;
      <accessor> private def _age: Int = Person.this._age;
      <accessor> private def _age_=(x$1: Int): Unit = Person.this._age = x$1;
      def age: Int = Person.this._age;
      def age_=(newAge: Int): Unit = {
        Person.this._age_=(newAge);
        scala.this.Predef.println("age changed to ".+(Person.this._age))
      }
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      var p: TestClassDef.Person = new TestClassDef.this.Person();
      p.age_=(26)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala allows non-alphanumerics in identifiers (in two ways):

case 1:

> (specialcharacters)*

```
scala> val ##*# = 1000000
scala> val #Alpha# = 1  // mixing alphanumerics not allowed
```

case 2:

> letter(alphanumerics)* _ (specialcharacters)*

```
scala> val k12? = 1       // doesn't work, _ is mandatory
scala> val k12_? = 1
scala> val k12_?*&^% = 1
scala> val k12_?Alpha = 1 // doesn't work, can't mix alphanumeric
```

Special cases:

Some symbols/combination-of-symbols are `reserved` e.g. `=` `#` `<%`

```
scala> val # =  1   // doesn't work
scala> val ### = 1  // works fine

scala> val <% = 1   // doesn't work
scala> val <%> = 1  // works fine
```

Some symbol-combinations are special, `_=` can be used in method names but not in variable names.

```
 scala> val k_= = 1  // doesn't work
 scala> def k_= = 1  // works fine
```

method names ending in `_=` are `setters`.

if a class/object's setter method `def x_=` is defined along with a parameter-less method of same name `def x`, then `x = e` is interpreted as `x_=(e)`