# Behavior of map() on Options

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-option

Im trying to map a JSONObject instance into an actual instance through Play Combinators. I am able to get the desrialization work correctly. The question is on the behavior of how map() works on an Option[JSONObject].

Option1:

```
jsonVal: Option[JSONObject] = getAsJson(input)
jsonVal.map(JSONUtil.fromJsonString(_.toString(), Blah.jsonReads))
```

Doesnt work, fails to compile as the _ is not resolved correctly. Compiler couldnt find the toString() on the object.

Option2:

```
jsonVal: Option[JSONObject] = getAsJson(input)
jsonVal.map(_.toString()).map(JSONUtil.fromJsonString(_, Blah.jsonReads))
```

Works !!. Can some one tell me why the Type of the default variable is not propagated when transformation is done as part of function argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't behavior of `map`, it's behavior of `_`. It's just a shortcut for the normal function expression ([in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)). In the first case you have

```
jsonVal.map(JSONUtil.fromJsonString(x => x.toString(), Blah.jsonReads))
```

which obviously doesn't work, and need to write the full version

```
jsonVal.map(x => JSONUtil.fromJsonString(x.toString(), Blah.jsonReads))
```