# Moving a graph of mathematical function

Tags: scala

I am faced with the following problem: I want to be able to modify a mathematical function in a way that you would move it in an x-y-graph. Therefore, I have two variables, x and y, which shall move the function upwards or to the right, respectively.

Let `f` be a function of type `Double => Double`, and let `x` and `y` be the aforementioned parameters. I want to do this:

```
def moveGraph(f: Double => Double, x: Double, y: Double): Double => Double = {
    f(_ - x) + y
}
```

This, however, throws the following compiler error:

```
Error:(5, 7) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$minus(x))
    f(_ - x) + y
      ^
```

How can I have `_` represent the parameter put into the function passed as `f` and still operate on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `moveGraph` function should look like this:

```
def moveGraph(f: Double => Double, x: Double, y: Double): Double => Double =
  p => f(p - x) + y
```

If you want to use the passed in parameter, you have to name it.

The compiler doesn't understand what `_` should stand for. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8000903/2032064) is a list of all possible usages for `_`.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to Mifeet answer, it is not like you *have to* name parameters. Just the shorthand notation for anonymous functions is quite simple and just expands in its current scope, so

```
f(_ - x) + y
```

becomes

```
f(param => param - x) + y
```

This is what compiler did, and complained that it doesn't know the type.

If `f` would expect a function `Int => Int` it would be a valid usage.

But you want to do something else here and you need to be explicit about your param

```
param => f(param - x) + y
```

Answer (score 1):

A fancier way to do it in scala is using function combinators:

```
def moveGraph(f: Double => Double, x: Double, y: Double): Double => Double  = 
 {p:Double => p - x } andThen f andThen y.+
```

(`(-x).+ andThen f andThen y.+` would be even nicer, but it doesn't' work in this case unfortunately, because `+` is overloaded, and scala gets confused by it).

Comment: `((_: Double) - x) andThen f andThen y.+` looks even a little fancier to me :p