# missing parameter type for `_`

Tags: scala

I'm trying to sort a list by how close the entries of a list are to num.

I decided to try use `sortWith`, but the following snippet:

```
list.sortWith(math.abs(_ - num) < math.abs(_ - num))
```

failed with missing parameter type for `_` in scala.
list is of type `List[Int]`.

Following the other threads, I know that `_` is somehow type ambiguous, but I'm not sure why, (and why the following snippet is not type ambiguous):

```
scala> val sortedDudes = dudes.sortWith(_.name < _.name)
sortedDudes: Array[Person] = Array(Al, Paul, Tyler)
```

([Source](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-sort-scala-sequences-seq-list-array-buffer-vector-ordering-ordered))

Comment: Make your code self-contained. What are `list` and `num`?

Comment: list is any List[Int], num is any integer.

Comment: `math.abs(_ - num)` is always (regardless of what context it appears in) short for `math.abs(x => x - num)`, which doesn't make sense and isn't what you intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 def foo = {
    val num = 2
    val list: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
    list.sortWith((a, b) => math.abs(a - num) < math.abs(b - num))
  }
```

work perfectly. It's because scala trying get `_` from `math.abs`, not `sortWith`

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, `_` can be used in a variety of different situations to mean different things. The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala) should help clarify a few of them.

Going back to the question, it seems the OP is trying to use `_` for parameter replacement. Consider the following example

```
List(1,2,5,7).filter(_ > 4)
```

Here `filter` takes a function of type `A => Unit`, so the above is shorthand for

```
List(1,2,5,7).filter(x => x > 4)
```

The underscore can stand for more than one parameter, but it must be used to refer to each parameter exactly once. This is why the `sortedDudes` snippet in the OP works. Therefore the following is legal.

```
List(1,2,5,7).reduce(_ + _)
```

which is shorthand for

```
List(1,2,5,7).reduce((a,b) => a + b)
```

I think the problem with the original snippet is that the compiler cannot unambiguously parse it into something of type `(A, A) => Boolean` as required by the `sortWith` method. We can give the compiler a little help as follows.

```
scala> def op(int: Int, num: Int) = math.abs(int - num)
op: (int: Int, num: Int)Int

scala> List(1,7,5,10).sortWith(op(_, 5) < op(_, 5))
res0: List[Int] = List(5, 7, 1, 10)
```