# Why doesn't placeholder work?

Tags: scala, methods

I have a class with the following method:

```
def message[A <: AnyRef](a: A) = a match {
  case str: String => messages ++ str
  case _: AnyRef => serializer.write(_) //compile error
}
```

I thought `_` may be used in any situation we don't want to use some specific character. But

```
def message[A <: AnyRef](a: A) = a match {
  case str: String => messages ++ str
  case a: AnyRef => serializer.write(a)
}
```

works fine.

What's a problem with `_`? What is the limit of its usage as method parameters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Answer (score 2):

`case _: AnyRef => serializer.write(_)` these wildcards are not related. Your first `_` means that you don't care about the name you just give it a type. The second `_` means that you don't care what will be provided to `write` at the moment and you will provide it later. The `_` in your code are not related, as you might have thought.

Answer (score 1):

Error happens in `serializer.write(_)`, because compiler does not have any possible values for this `_`. For example, if you'd write `List(1, 2, 3) map (_ + 2)`, that could be expanded to `List(1, 2, 3) map (x => x + 2)`, and *there* `x` might be hidden with `_`.