# What's meaning of this underscore?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am reading akka-http source codes, here is source code of `akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.RouteDirectives`, take the `complete` method as example, can anybody tell what's meaning of the underscore in `StandardRoute(_.complete(m))`?

```
package akka.http.scaladsl.server
package directives

import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import StatusCodes._

/**
 * @groupname route Route directives
 * @groupprio route 200
 */
trait RouteDirectives {

  ....
  ....

  /**
   * Completes the request using the given arguments.
   *
   * @group route
   */
  def complete(m: ⇒ ToResponseMarshallable): StandardRoute =
    StandardRoute(_.complete(m))
}

object RouteDirectives extends RouteDirectives {
  private val _reject = StandardRoute(_.reject())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StandardRoute(_.complete(m))` is equivalent to `StandardRoute(x => x.complete(m))`

Here underscore refers to `x`. If you want to know the use cases of underscore in scala. Please check [this link (Uses of underscore in Scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)

Here is the code from akka http library

```
object StandardRoute {
  def apply(route: Route): StandardRoute = route match {
    case x: StandardRoute ⇒ x
    case x                ⇒ new StandardRoute { def apply(ctx: RequestContext) = x(ctx) }
  }

  /**
   * Converts the StandardRoute into a directive that never passes the request to its inner route
   * (and always returns its underlying route).
   */
  implicit def toDirective[L: Tuple](route: StandardRoute): Directive[L] =
    Directive[L] { _ ⇒ route }
}
```

Route is nothing but function

```
type Route = RequestContext ⇒ Future[RouteResult]
```

**Explanation:**

Consider this object Number. This object's apply method takes a function. Now see how this Number object will be used.

```
object Number {
 def apply(f: String => Int): Int = {
  f("123") 
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
Number(_.toInt)
```

or

```
Number(x => x.toInt)
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> object Number {
     |      def apply(f: String => Int): Int = {
     |       f("123") 
     |      }
     |     }
defined object Number

scala> Number(_.toInt)
res0: Int = 123

scala> Number(x => x.toInt)
res1: Int = 123
```

Comment: nope, The apply method of StandardRoute only accepts a Route instance.

Comment: @LaurenceGeng route must be extending a function then

Comment: @LaurenceGeng `StandardRoute(_.complete(m))` can be replaced with `StandardRoute(x => x.complete(m))`

Comment: @LaurenceGeng [Route](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/#akka.http.scaladsl.server.package@Route=akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext=>scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]) is of type `(RequestContext) ⇒ Future[RouteResult]`

Comment: @LaurenceGeng thats it ... Route  if function and StandardRoute apply method takes a Route. I think its clear for you now

Comment: @LaurenceGeng StandardRoute apply method will be something like this `def apply(RequestContext ⇒ Future[RouteResult])`

Comment: @LaurenceGeng Route is just a alias for `RequestContext) ⇒ Future[RouteResult]`