# _ must follow method; cannot follow () => Boolean

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

Hi I'm trying to run my code, I double checked everything. It supposed to work, I mean IDE doesn't give any warnings. But when it is compiling I am getting this error

```
Error:(20, 40) _ must follow method; cannot follow () => Boolean
        properties += new Property(propName, formula _)
```

here is code part which causes this error

```
def property(propName: String)(formula: () =>  Boolean)  {
        properties += new Property(propName, formula _)
    }
```

this is the Property class

```
class Property(val name: String, val func: () => Boolean)
```

what's the thing that I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the underscore here. The underscore would only be needed when you want to convert a method to a function via eta-expansion. This isn't necessary here because `formula` is already a function of the type `() => Boolean`, which is what the `Property` class is looking for.

```
def property(propName: String)(formula: () =>  Boolean)  {
    properties += new Property(propName, formula)
}
```

Comment: So that's why it doesn't give errors when I make it   `def property(propName: String)(formula: =>  Boolean)` ?

Comment: `=> Boolean` is not completely the same as `Function1[Boolean]`. You will notice if you leave off the `_` that you *will* get an error. This is [yet another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8001065/1374461) usage of `_` in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

Just like the warning says. `_` must follow a method to turn it into a function. `formula` already is a function. So you can just pass it like this:

```
properties += new Property(propName, formula)
```