# What is the usage of _ in Int => Int = _ + 1

Tags: scala

In the code below, what is the classification (or technical name) of the usage of the underscore character?

```
scala> def f: Int => Int = _ + 1
f: Int => Int

scala> f(2)
res0: Int = 3
```

Comment: Placeholder. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)

> ... sometimes called underscore syntax for a function literal, we are
>   not even bothering to name the argument to the function, using _
>   represent the sole argument. When using this notation, we can only
>   reference the function parameter once in the body of the function (if
>   we mention _ again, it refers to another argument to the function)

In your case, doing:

```
def f: Int => Int = _ + 1
```

would be the same thing as this:

```
def f: Int => Int = x => x + 1
```

which may seem unnecessary, but becomes pretty handy for passing anonymous functions to higher ordered functions (which are functions that take functions as arguments):

```
def higherOrder(f: Int => Int) = { /* some implementation */ }

// Using your function you declared already
higherOrder(f)  

// Passing an anonymous function
higherOrder((x: Int) => x + 1)
higherOrder((x) => x + 1)
higherOrder(x => x + 1)

// Passing an anonymous function with underscore syntax
higherOrder(_ + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as an input which will be supplied by caller

```
scala> def incrementByOne: Int => Int = _ + 1
incrementByOne: Int => Int
```

What yo get back is a function that takes `Int` and returns an `Int`.

```
X => Y
```

In return type means a function that take type `X` as input and return type `Y` as output. now `X` and `Y` could be any types.

To complete the example, you would call it as

```
scala> incrementByOne(10)
res0: Int = 11

scala> incrementByOne(99)
res1: Int = 100

scala>
```

which took `Int` as input (`10` and `99`) and returned `Int` as output (`11` and `100`)

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I was looking for a syntactic "name" when the underscore is used in such a way in an anonymous function. From the link given in the 1st post. [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala). It is called "Placeholder Syntax". Not really intuitive but it's Ok as long as there is a name.