# Scala placeholder _ variable

Tags: scala

I am learning from this site
http://naildrivin5.com/scalatour/wiki_pages/ExplcitlyTypedSelfReferences/

```
trait BaseComponent {
    protected var label:Label = _
}
```

In this case what does the placeholder _ stands for?What would be the alternative?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala?s=1|2.3155 for other uses of `_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The placeholder syntax for a variable assings the *default value* to the variable. Assuming `Label` inherits `AnyRef`, that would be `null`.

The Scala language specification [lays this out explicitly](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html):

> ### 4.2 Variable Declarations and Definitions:
>
> A variable definition `var x: T = _` can appear only as a member of a template. It introduces a mutable field with type `T` and a default initial value. The default value depends on the type `T` as follows:

```
| default | type T                           |
|---------|----------------------------------|
| 0       | Int or one of its subrange types |
| 0L      | Long                             |
| 0.0f    | Float                            |
| 0.0d    | Double                           |
| false   | Boolean                          |
| ()      | Unit                             |
| null    | all other types                  |
```