# Understanding Scala's underscore and asterisk magic

Tags: scala

I am reading and practicing Scala, and I found this [blog](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/23/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-10-staying-dry-with-higher-order-functions.html).

Reading the part about **Composing Predicates** I see this piece of code

```
def complement[A](predicate: A => Boolean) = (a: A) => !predicate(a)

def any[A](predicates: (A => Boolean)*): A => Boolean =
  a => predicates.exists(pred => pred(a))

def none[A](predicates: (A => Boolean)*) = complement(any(predicates: _*))

def every[A](predicates: (A => Boolean)*) = none(predicates.view.map(complement(_)): _*)
```

I have a python background and would like to understand the meaning of underscore and asterisk, when used alone or together, it's quite strange to make sense of it, specially for **none** and **every** definitions.

Comment: `_` in general means "something whose name I don't care about". You may want to explore this answer regarding all its possible meanings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8001065/3314107

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SomeExpression*` means "a sequence of 0 or more elements"

`_` can be used to specify "a parameter that we do not need to name"

The parameter to `none` is "a sequence of predicates containing 0 or more elements", and a "predicate" is a function that takes `A` and returns `Boolean`.

The parameter to `any` is an array, so the value passed in must be converted to an array, which is done by `_*`

The parameter to `every` is an array, whose name is not important because there is only one. It can be passed to `complement` as `_`

Comment: `_*` is a vararg, not "a sequence of 0 or more elements" To see the difference apply splat operator to a Seq.

Answer (score 8):

```
def any[A](predicates: (A => Boolean)*)
```

produces the same function as

```
def any[A](predicates: Seq[A => Boolean])
```

except that you can call it like `any(a, b, c)` instead of `any(List(a, b, c))` (the compiler transforms the call sites).

Given that `any` is a varargs function, calling `any(a)` enters the body of `any` with `predicates = List(a)`. But if `a` is already a sequence, this isn't what you want. That's what the `: _*` notation is for: it tells the Scala compiler "treat this as a sequence of parameters for varargs".

This is roughly equivalent to writing in Python,

```
def complement(predicate):
    return lambda a: not predicate(a)

def any_(*predicates):
    return lambda a: any(pred(a) for pred in predicates)

def none(*predicates):
    return complement(any_(*predicates))

def every(*predicates):
    return none(*map(complement, predicates))
```

Comment: `Seq`, not `Array`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Right, my mistake. `Array` is possible with a `@varargs` annotation for Java comparability, but it's `Seq` for plain Scala code.

Comment: what about the definition for **every** where `_` and `_*` are used in the same line? **complement** accepts only one predicate, but isn't `_` a Seq in that context and that's why later on `_*` can be used? That last line is the most difficult to understand.

Comment: @DiegoRueda Ah, in that case `complement(_)` is shorthand for `a => complement(a)`. `predicates.view.map(...)` is like `predicates.map(...)` but lazy instead of eager, and returns a `Seq`. Then the `: _*` treatment is just like the previous.

Comment: There are [many uses and meanings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8001065) of the `_` placeholder in Scala.