# map function in Scala

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, map-function

In **Scala** programming use an anonymous function is a usual thing . when i decide to creat a vector as out put of an anonymous function from two different ways 
way one :
`var hold1=(1 to 5).map(_*2)`
way two:
  `var hold2=(1 to 5).map(2*)`
I want to know what is the difference between those two declaration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short - they are exactly the same.
First approach:

```
var hold1 = (1 to 5).map(_*2)
```

Let's rewrite this another way to demonstrate what's really happening under the hood (no syntactic sugar)

```
var hold1 = (1 to 5).map(number => number.*(2))
```

Second approach:

```
var hold2 = (1 to 5).map(2*)
```

Rewrite again:

```
var hold2 = (1 to 5).map(number => 2.*(number))
```

All that is happening is in first way are invoking the `*` def on the number 2 and in the second way we are invoking the `*` def on the number.

Comment: it might be interesting to look at the generated code, however. `_ * 2` almost certainly creates an anonymous lambda, but `2 *` might not.

Comment: They are only exactly the same if you assume that `Int.*` is symmetric! That is not true in the general case.

Comment: Why does the second version which calls the `.*` method not require the `_`?  Should it not be `(1 to 5).map(2 * _)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Both are exactly same. You can use underscore character in many different ways. Refer this link for more details.

[What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)