# check empty for option string in scala

Tags: scala

I want to check for empty string in scala .If the string is empty return an option else return a None

**Updated 1**

```
 case class Student(name:String,subject:Symbol = Symbol("Default")))

  def getStudentName(name :Option[String]):Option[Student]={
     name.flatMap(_ => Option(Student(name.get)))
  }
```

**Updated 2**

Scenario 1:

```
 call 1- print(getStudentName(Option("abc")))//Some(Student(abc))
 Call 2- print(getStudentName(Option("")))//return Some(Student())
```

Scenario 2:

```
case class Emp(id:Int)

  def getEmp(id:Option[String]):Option[Emp]={
    id.flatMap(_ => Option(Emp(id.get.toInt)))
  }

  print(getEmp(Option("123")))
  print(getEmp(Option("")))//gives number format exception
```

I want to return `None` when I pass `""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is too much wrapping with `Option` going on, you can easily do:

Scenario 1:

```
name
  .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
  .map(Student(_))
```

Scenaro 2:

```
id
  .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
  .filter(_.matches("^[0-9]*$")) // ensure it's a number so .toInt is safe
  .map(id => Emp(id.toInt))
```

Comment: thks it works but I have updated my question can u please check

Comment: case where we need to change string to int-Can you please have a look at updated question

Comment: Please check for scenerio 1 the  `subject` field is also added which gives compile error with map

Comment: That's because the original case class has an additional argument now. See updated answer

Comment: can u explain the _ used in scenerio 1

Comment: It's syntactic sugar, see a similar answer I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302223/map-function-in-scala/43302468#43302468

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154703/discussion-between-coder25-and-tanjin).

Comment: I have few more queries I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282620/efficient-way-to-match-case-object-in-scala