# Efficient way to match case object in scala

Tags: scala

I want to get Student and employee who works in country India and china

```
object Countries {
  sealed trait Country {def name: String}
  case object FRANCE extends Country {val name = "FRANCE"}
  case object INDIA extends Country {val name = "INDIA"}
  case object CHINA extends Country {val name = "CHINA"}
  val list = Seq(FRANCE, INDIA, CHINA)
}

def getCountry: Option[Countries.Country] ={
  //some DB call to return country based on some parameters .I assume INDIA here
  Option(Countries.INDIA)
}

case class Student(name: String, id: Symbol = Symbol("Id"))

def getStudentName(name: Option[String]): Option[Student]={
  val std = name
    .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
    .map(Student(_))

  getCountry.collect {
    case Countries.INDIA => std
    case Countries.CHINA => std
  }.flatten              
}

case class Emp(id: Int)

def getEmp(id: Option[String]): Option[Emp] = {
  val emp = id.flatMap(_ => Option(Emp(id.get.toInt)))
  getCountry.collect {
    case Countries.INDIA => emp
    case Countries.CHINA => emp
  }.flatten
}
```

Is there any efficient way to avoid the repeated code using `collect` and case matching I have done .

Comment: I downvoted because the code is nowhere near compiling, making the question not understandable for me.

Comment: what do you mean by "efficient"? Do you mean readability (e.g. not repeating itself) or anything else (e.f. better performing)?

Comment: @C4stor please check

Comment: @TzachZohar It means readability

Comment: @C4stor "nowhere near compiling" is an exaggeration, had one mistake (`Country` instead of `Countries.Country`) ...

Comment: Well, there's a def in the middle of nothing, and the declared return type of the functions  are not respected by the actual returns. So yeah, I couldn't fix it by simply correcting typo, and I surrendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def ifCountry[T](result: => Option[T], countries: Country*) = getCountry
  .filter(countries.toSet)
  .flatMap(_ => result)


def getStudentName(name: Option[String]) = ifCountry(
   name.filterNot(_.isEmpty).map(Student(_)),
   INDIA, CHINA
)

def getEmp(id: Option[String]) = ifCountry(
    id.map(Emp(_)), 
    INDIA, CHINA
}
```

Comment: can anyone explain `result: => Option[T]` and  `:=>` symbol in scala

Comment: it is the syntax for `by name` parameters. That means that the parameter will be evaluated only when needed, not before.

Comment: An argument whose type is `=> A` is an argument whose type is `A` but which will be passed by name rather than by value. That is, it will be evaluated every time that it occurs in the code, rather than exactly once when the function is called.

Comment: Another way to see it is you're actually passing a function give an A instead of an instance of A, and this function will be called every time you need it.

Comment: Yes, it is actually just a syntactic sugar for `Function0`