# Assigning existing function to variable

Tags: scala

I want to assign an existing function to a variable. According to [this](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-functions-as-variables-values-in-scala-fp#assigning-an-existing-function-method-to-a-function-variable) site, it is as easy as:

```
val p = scala.math.pow(_, _)
pow: (Double, Double) => Double = <function2>
```

but when I try to do the same thing in my code it does not work.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val p = scala.math.min(_, _)
    val func = if ( args(0).equalsIgnoreCase("min"))  math.min(_,_) else math.max(_,_)
}
```

I thought this maybe due to use of `if` and `else` condition in same line, but I get error when assigning value to variable `p` as well.

Error I get:

> missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) =>
>   scala.math.min(x$1, x$2))

Why does it not work for me and how can I fix it?

Comment: `val p = scala.math.min _`

Comment: @dmitry Why does pow need 2 underscores and min and max will do with just 1? i.e. how do you know if 1 underscore is sufficient ?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the top voted answer here, specifically the ending segment. Also scala.math.pow _ single underscore works just as well. The short answer to knowing what is sufficient is to see if it compiles successfully :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type parameters must be defined for your `func`:

```
val func: (Int, Int) => Int = if (args.head.equalsIgnoreCase("min"))  math.min(_,_) else math.max(_,_)
```

Alternatively as user dmitry pointed out, use a single underscore:

```
val func = if (args.head.equalsIgnoreCase("min"))  math.min _ else math.max _
```

However it seems like you are a beginner to the language - personally I would practice explicitly stating the types of interest like in the first example until you have a better handle on things.

Answer (score 1):

There is just a single `scala.math.pow` method, but there are multiple overloads of `min` and `max`: `def min(x: Double, y: Double): Double`, `def min(x: Int, y: Int): Int` etc. Without providing expected argument type, Scala can't know which one you mean. I'd write e.g. `val p = scala.math.min(_: Int, _: Int)` or `val p = scala.math.min(_: Double, _: Double)` (or you can specify the type of `p` directly as in Tanjin's answer).

`val p = min _` happens to work because the `min(x: Int, y: Int)` overload is the most specific one, but I think it's a bad idea to rely on it when starting.