# Difference between underscore (_) and triple question marks (???) in scala

Tags: scala, syntax

I am in the middle of writing some code so I wanted to leave a method unimplemented which I am calling but that pathflow is not hitting based on input I am providing. The method looks like this

```
object HbaseStore {
  def get() = _
}
```

But the above code threw an exception

> HbaseStore.scala:24: error: unbound placeholder parameter
>
> [INFO]   def get() = _

But when I replaced `_` with `???` code executed successfully. I am just curious to know what is the difference between these two. As far as I know, `_` provides default values so I assumed it would define an empty function here and return `Nothing`.

Comment: The Scala underscore, `_`, does **not** provide default values. It actually has many uses/meanings, some of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` is a placeholder syntax, which is used to bind values. Placeholder syntax is used in many scenarios, for example:
In case of list:

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4,5)
//To print each value we can do:
x.map(res => println(res)) 
//Now, we can use placeholder syntax to bind res value.
x.map(println(_))
```

Pattern matching:

```
val x = "some value"
x match {
case x:String => //convert to lowercase and print.
case res@_ => //here, type doesnot matter I just want to get that value and print as it is. println(res)
```

So, basically, you use placeholder syntax if you want to have the value without knowing its type.

On the other hand, `???` is assigned to method or variables as value in case you don't want to provide implementation.

e.g. `def doSomething() => ???`
here, `doSomething()` method is not implemented, and you need to provide or override implementation later. Note, that you cannot use variables/methods without implementations and you will get exception in case you try to invoke it. e.g. `doSomething()` will fail in above case.

Comment: Thanks @Ra Ka. Appreciated your answer

Comment: @sachinjain024 it's worth noting that `???` is not actually special syntax like `_` is.  `???` is just a method defined in `scala.predef`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `_` as a default value you need to provide a type of this value. For example `var x: Any = _` will be initialized with `null` but `var x: Int = _` will be initialized with `0`.
Regarding `???` :
You can click on the definition of `???` in IDE:

`def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError`

Since `Nothing` is a subtype of any given type, it works.