# Why does passing some functions in scala require _

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Getting to know scala better, I came across a behaviour I cannot explain.
The below code works fine:

```
def triple(x: Double) = 3 * x
Array(3.14,1.42,3.9).map(triple)
```

However, If I call the scala ceil function in math library then I will need to pass an _ for it to work

```
def valueAtOneQuarter(f: (Double)=> Double) = f(0.25)
valueAtOneQuarter(sqrt _)
```

What is special about the _ in this context from the function call in the earlier piece of code.

Comment: it actually works fine for me without underscore in both cases

Comment: The expansion works for me too and happens automatically, there's no need to use `_` as Dima said.

Answer (score 3):

The underscore is actually expanded to a function.

So `sqrt _` gets turned into the function `a => sqrt(a)`.

You will notice that this expanded function matches the parameter type f of the valueatonequarter method.

In more general terms, the underscore is sometimes needed to flag to the compiler to turn the method (a method is declared using def) into a function (methods and functions are similar but not the same thing). The compiler will attempt to automatically convert the method to a function for you but in some cases it needs additional pointers (like an explicit type declaration or _). See here for a full explanation of eta expansion and partial functions: https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/on-method-invocations-or-what-exactly-is-eta-expansion-1019b37e010c

Comment: This does not answer the question why it requires underscore in one case, but not in the other.

Answer (score 1):

A method and a function are not the same in Scala.

You define a method this way:

```
def method(x:Double):Double = ...
```

But you define a function using this way:

```
val func = (x: Double):Double => {...}
```

when you pass a function as a parameter to a method it must be a function, but not a method.

So you must use underscore to make a function from a method.

Sometimes Scala uses “Eta Expansion” capability to automatically convert the method into a function. But in some cases you must do it manually

Comment: Thanks seems _ has different meaning in different context in scala. its almost like if there was some gap _ is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Answering since the existing answers don't really explain when `_` is needed, just "sometimes" or "in some cases".

A very important concept to understand in Scala is *expected type*. In your first example the expected type for argument of `map` is `Double => B` with some unknown `B`; in the second it's `Double => Double`. When the expected type is a function type and a method name is passed, it'll be automatically converted to a function. So, as comments say, the second example works without `_`. It's only necessary where there is no expected type, say

```
val f = sqrt _
```

There can also be issues when the method is overloaded, but there just adding `_` generally won't work either; instead, you'll specify the argument type to show which method is used, e.g. `max(_: Int, _: Int)` or `max(_: Double, _: Double)`.

> Thanks seems _ has different meaning in different context in scala

Yes, quite a few: [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)