# How to create RDD[Map(Int,Int)] using Spark and Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following simple code in Java. This code creates and fills the `Map` with 0 values.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<=20; i++) { myMap.put(i, 0); }
```

I want to create a similar RDD using Spark and Scala. I tried this approach, but it returns me `RDD[(Any) => (Any,Int)]` instead of `RDD[Map(Int,Int)]`. What am I doing wrong?

```
val data = (0 to 20).map(_ => (_,0))
val myMapRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are creating are `tuples`. Instead you need to create `Map` and `parallelize` as below

```
val data = (0 to 20).map(x => Map(x -> 0))         //data: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Vector(Map(0 -> 0), Map(1 -> 0), Map(2 -> 0), Map(3 -> 0), Map(4 -> 0), Map(5 -> 0), Map(6 -> 0), Map(7 -> 0), Map(8 -> 0), Map(9 -> 0), Map(10 -> 0), Map(11 -> 0), Map(12 -> 0), Map(13 -> 0), Map(14 -> 0), Map(15 -> 0), Map(16 -> 0), Map(17 -> 0), Map(18 -> 0), Map(19 -> 0), Map(20 -> 0))

val myMapRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(data)       //myMapRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at test.sc:19
```

Comment: Will I be able to obtain values by keys from `myMapRDD`?

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, `(0 to 20).map(_ => (_, 0))` would not compile, as it has invalid `placeholder` syntax.  I believe you might be looking for something like below instead:

```
val data = (0 to 20).map( _->0 )
```

which would generate a list of key-value pairs, and is really just a placeholder shorthand for:

```
val data = (0 to 20).map( n => n->0 )

// data: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector(
//   (0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (5,0), (6,0), (7,0), (8,0), (9,0), (10,0),
//   (11,0), (12,0), (13,0), (14,0), (15,0), (16,0), (17,0), (18,0), (19,0), (20,0)
// )
```

A RDD is an immtable collection (e.g. `Seq`, `Array`) of data.  To create a RDD of `Map[Int,Int]`, you would expand `data` inside a `Map` which in turn gets placed inside a `Seq` collection:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Map(data: _*)))

rdd.collect
// res1: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Array(
//   Map(0 -> 0, 5 -> 0, 10 -> 0, 14 -> 0, 20 -> 0, 1 -> 0, 6 -> 0, 9 -> 0, 13 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 17 -> 0,
//       12 -> 0, 7 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 18 -> 0, 16 -> 0, 11 -> 0, 8 -> 0, 19 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 15 -> 0)
// )
```

Note that, as is, this RDD consists of only a single `Map`, and certainly you can assemble as many `Map`s as you wish in a RDD.

```
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Map((0 to 4).map( _->0 ): _*),
  Map((5 to 9).map( _->0 ): _*),
  Map((10 to 14).map( _->0 ): _*),
  Map((15 to 19).map( _->0 ): _*)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't `parallelize` a `Map`, as `parallelize` takes a `Seq`. What you can achieve is creating an `RDD[(Int, Int)]`, which however does not enforce the uniqueness of keys. To perform operation by key, you can leverage [`PairRDDFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions), that despite this limitation can end up being useful for your use case.

Let's try at least to get an `RDD[(Int, Int)]`.

You used a slightly "wrong" syntax when applying the `map` to your range.

The `_` placeholder can have [different meanings depending on the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala). The two meanings that got mixed up in your snippet of code are:

- a placeholder for an anonymous function parameter that is not going to be used (as in `(_ => 42)`, a function which ignores its input and always returns `42`)
- a positional placeholder for arguments in anonymous functions (as in `(_, 42)` a function that takes one argument and returns a tuple where the first element is the input and the second is the number `42`)

The above examples are simplified and do not account for type inference as they only wish to point out two of the meanings of the `_` placeholder that got mixed up in your snippet of code.

The first step is to use one of the two following functions to create the pairs that are going to be part of the map, either

```
a => (a, 0)
```

or

```
(_, 0)
```

and after parallelizing it you can get the `RDD[(Int, Int)]`, as follows:

```
val pairRdd = sc.parallelize((0 to 20).map((_, 0)))
```

I believe it's worth noting here, that mapping on the local collection is going to be executed eagerly and bound to your driver's resources, while you can obtain the same final result by parallelizing the collection first and then mapping the pair-creating function on the `RDD`.

Now, as mentioned you don't have a distributed map, but rather a collection of key-value pairs where the key uniqueness is not enforced. But you can work pretty seamlessly with those values using [`PairRDDFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions), which you obtain automatically by importing [`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$@rddToPairRDDFunctions[K,V](rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)])(implicitkt:scala.reflect.ClassTag[K],implicitvt:scala.reflect.ClassTag[V],implicitord:Ordering[K]):org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[K,V]) (or without having to do anything in the `spark-shell` as the import has already been done for your), which will *decorate* your `RDD` leveraging Scala's [implicit conversions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html).

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions

pairRdd.mapValues(_ + 1).foreach(println)
```

will print the following

```
(10,1)
(11,1)
(12,1)
(13,1)
(14,1)
(15,1)
(16,1)
(17,1)
(18,1)
(19,1)
(20,1)
(0,1)
(1,1)
(2,1)
(3,1)
(4,1)
(5,1)
(6,1)
(7,1)
(8,1)
(9,1)
```

You can learn more about working with key-value pairs with the RDD API on the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs).