# Lists of attributes of objects in a List

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a list of objects in Scala. Let's say:

```
list: List[ClassX] = List(objectA, objectB, objectC)
```

and the class

```
class ClassX{

  var attrA
  var attrB

}
```

Is there a predefined method call, if I want to get attrA of all objects in my list?

Comment: `list.map(_.attrA)`

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510844/pondering-name-of-pattern-seen-in-elm-and-if-other-similar-cases/48511108#48511108).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
val as = list.map(_.attrA)
```

`as` is a `List[A]`, where `A` is the type of `attrA` in `ClassX`.

The above is a shorthand notation for:

```
val as = list.map(a => a.attrA)
```