# What does `= _` do in Scala property definition

Tags: scala

I stumble upon scala code like this:

```
var folderName: String = _
```

What does the `= _` do? And is there a proper name for this language feature?

Comment: Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala) and search for "default".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`= _` is used to set the default value when initialising a variable.

1. `var s: String = _` will set `s` equal to `null`.
2. `var i: Int = _` will set `i` equal to `0`.