# Underscore usage when passing a function in Scala

Tags: scala

I am following this tutorial and I see this code:

```
def totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter(donutType: String)(quantity: Int)(f: Double => Double): Double = {
  println(s"Calculating total cost for $quantity $donutType")
  val totalCost = 2.50 * quantity
  println("inside totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter")
  f(totalCost)
}

def applyDiscount(totalCost: Double): Double = {
  val discount = 2 // assume you fetch discount from database
  totalCost - discount
}

println(s"Total cost of 5 Glazed Donuts with discount function = ${totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("Glazed Donut")(5)(applyDiscount(_))}")
```

What is the point of the `_` in `applyDiscount(_)`? I can also remove it and just pass the function by name like this `applyDiscount` and the code works. What is the point of the underscore? Is it the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

`applyDiscount(_)` is [placeholder syntax for anonymous functions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions). This expands to:

```
x => applyDiscount(x)
```

When you pass the `applyDiscount` method to the function, i.e:

```
totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("5")(applyDiscount)
```

Then scalac will perform [eta-expansion](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion), which means turning a method to a function value.

Do these have exactly the same semantics? Close, but not quite. Consider the following example given in [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala) (slightly modified, full credit to @Owen for the example and the provided answer)

```
trait PlaceholderExample {
  def process[A](f: A => Unit)

  val set: Set[_ => Unit]

  set.foreach(process) // Error 
  set.foreach(process(_)) // No Error
}
```

The first errors at compile time while the second succeeds, why is that? Let's look at the code compiled with `-Xprint:typer`:

```
λ scalac -Xprint:typer Test.scala
FooBar.scala:11: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [A](A => Unit) => Unit
 required: (Function1[_, Unit]) => ?
  set.foreach(process) // Error
              ^
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]]
package yuval.tests {
  abstract trait PlaceholderExample extends scala.AnyRef {
    def /*PlaceholderExample*/$init$(): Unit = {
      ()
    };
    def process[A](f: A => Unit): Unit;
    <stable> <accessor> val set: Set[Function1[_, Unit]];
    PlaceholderExample.this.set.foreach[U](process);
    PlaceholderExample.this.set.foreach[Unit](((x$1: Function1[_, Unit]) => PlaceholderExample.this.process[_$1](x$1)))
  }
}
```

First thing you see is a compilation error because scalac was unable to eta-expand the method `process` from a polymorphic method to a monomorphic function. Meaning, when scalac attempts to bind `A` to an actual type, it looks for a type `(_ => Unit) => ?` but fails because `_` (an existential) is not a type.

On the other hand, the second example which is expanded to `x => process(x)` compiles because when scalac encounters a lambda expression with no explicit type annotation, it looks at the type of the method signature (in our case, `foreach` expects a `_ => Unit`, which is classified as a type) and successfully binds the type argument to `process`.

Thus, in most cases you'll find that the two are isomorphic (although they really aren't)(even IntelliJ recommended that I can write one instead of the other), but there are edge cases which does distinguish one from the other.