# Is this a by-name function parameter? Why is the wildcard optional?

Tags: scala

I am following [this](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-3-beginner-tutorial-using-functions-scala/scala-tutorial-learn-create-val-function-val-vs-def/) tutorial and I see this code:

```
    println("\nStep 1: How to define a higher order function which takes another function as parameter")
    def totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter(donutType: String)(quantity: Int)(f: Double => Double): Double = {
        println(s"Calculating total cost for $quantity $donutType")
        val totalCost = 2.50 * quantity
        f(totalCost)
    }

    println("\nStep 2: How to define and pass a def function to a higher order function")
    def applyDiscount(totalCost: Double): Double = {
        val discount = 2 // assume you fetch discount from database
        totalCost - discount
    }
    println(s"Total cost of 5 Glazed Donuts with discount def function = ${totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("Glazed Donut")(5)(applyDiscount(_))}")

    println("\nStep 3: How to define and pass a val function to a higher order function")
    val applyDiscountValueFunction = (totalCost: Double) => {
        val discount = 2 // assume you fetch discount from database
        totalCost - discount
    }
    println(s"Total cost of 5 Glazed Donuts with discount val function = ${totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("Glazed Donut")(5)(applyDiscountValueFunction)}")
```

The author says:

> The function has a by-name parameter which is expected to be a function that has a parameter of type Double and will also return a type of Double.

Is that true? What would be a by-value parameter here? Is the function lazily evaluated which makes it a by-name parameter? Is that true?

Why does the author use the wildcard when passing in `applyDiscount` but not when passing in `applydiscountValueFunction`? Both work without the wildcard operator.

Comment: In the sentence: *The function has a by-name parameter*, to which function are you referring?

Answer (score 2):

`applyDiscount(_)` transforms the method into a function, using placeholder syntax for anonymous functions.

This process can be automated by the compiler (using a technique called *eta-expansion*) whenever a function type is expected and a method is passed instead, which is exactly the case in the example.

(for a more thorough discussion, refer to this answer: [Underscore usage when passing a function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630017/underscore-usage-when-passing-a-function-in-scala/50631037#50631037))

So you're right in saying that this

```
totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("Glazed Donut")(5)(applyDiscount)
```

would work anyway, because the compiler will transform the `applyDiscount` to a function automatically.

---

As per the by-name parameter, what the author is calling `by-name` parameter (the parameter `f`) is really just a parameter of type `Double => Double`, so it seems he's using incorrect terminology.

A by-name parameter in Scala is expressed using `=>` like this:

```
def someMethod(someParam: => Double): Double = // ...
```

In this example `someParam` is a by name parameter, meaning it won't be evaluated at call-site.

Comment: `applyDiscount(_)` is not eta-expansion. [See my answer to his previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631037/1870803).

Comment: I've updated the answer, correcting it and linking it to yours