# meaning of scala underscore in list construct

Tags: scala, lambda, syntactic-sugar

In the following code from "functional-programming-in-scala, what is `_` mean here? I think it represent the result of sequence(t), but when I replaced it with sequence(t), it gives me an compile error. Why is that? What can I do to make this _ explicit?

Edit: I'm confused that whether this `_` should be expand into result of sequence(t), list all use case for underscore [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)  doesn't help here, I already reviewed it.

```
@ def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] =
  a match {
      case Nil => Some(Nil)
      case h :: t => h flatMap (hh => sequence(t) map (hh :: _))
  }

defined function sequence

@

@ sequence(List(Some(1), Some(2))
  )
res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))
```

Replace `_` with sequence(t)

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] =
a match {
    case Nil => Some(Nil)
    case h :: t => h flatMap (hh => sequence(t) map (hh :: sequence(t)))
}
cmd4.sc:4: value :: is not a member of Option[List[A]]
case h :: t => h flatMap (hh => sequence(t) map (hh :: sequence(t)))
                                                    ^
Compilation Failed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)

Comment: I saw that already before ask this question. It doesn't help. And what I want to know is how it work specifically in this case. It shouldn't be a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every context, `hh :: _` is simply a shortcut for `_.::(hh)`, which in turn is a shortcut for `x => x.::(h)`, or `x => hh :: x`. The type of the argument in this case is `List[A]` (because it's a list of `A`s inside an `Option`). Therefore, your code does the same as the following code:

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = 
  a match {
    case Nil => Some(Nil)
    case h :: t => h flatMap (hh => sequence(t) map ((xs: List[A]) => hh :: xs))
  }
```

Whether it's used inside `flatMap` or somewhere else, is completely irrelevant.