# what is does it mean println(_)?

Tags: scala, lambda, syntactic-sugar, scala-placeholder-syntax

I have this piece of code in scala

```
val wordCounts = logData.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
wordCounts.foreach(println(_))
```

So what does println(_) mean and what should it print?

Comment: you will find what `_` mean: [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala). Your code is equivalnet to `wordCounts.foreach(x => println(x))
`, where `_` represent each element

Comment: @prayagupd I've already tried to use this Q/A as duplicate target today, the last questioner didn't like it: too much unrelated stuff, had to reopen... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the section ["Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions" of the Spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions),

```
println(_)
```

is a shortcut for the anonymous function literal

```
w => println(w)
```

which in turn is a shortcut for something like

```
(w: (String, Int)) => println(w)
```

in this particular case.

Therefore,

```
wordCounts.foreach(println(_))
```

simply prints every element of `wordCounts`.

Note that it can also be written even shorter:

```
wordCounts foreach println
```