# How does type inference work for a selection with placeholder syntax?

Tags: scala

I'm reading through some code examples from the exercises from the book Functional Programming in Scala (but my question is not related to FP).
https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/state/State.scala

I have a Scala syntax question about the following line:

```
val int: Rand[Int] = _.nextInt
```

from this excerpt:

```
trait RNG {
  def nextInt: (Int, RNG) // Should generate a random `Int`. We'll later define other functions in terms of `nextInt`.
}

object RNG {

  case class Simple(seed: Long) extends RNG {
    def nextInt: (Int, RNG) = {
      val newSeed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL // `&` is bitwise AND. We use the current seed to generate a new seed.
      val nextRNG = Simple(newSeed) // The next state, which is an `RNG` instance created from the new seed.
      val n = (newSeed >>> 16).toInt // `>>>` is right binary shift with zero fill. The value `n` is our new pseudo-random integer.
      (n, nextRNG) // The return value is a tuple containing both a pseudo-random integer and the next `RNG` state.
    }
  }

  type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)

  val int: Rand[Int] = _.nextInt
}
```

What does the underscore refer to here? What even is `int` in this case? Is it just a function, specifically `nextInt`? But if so how does the underscore point to that function?

Comment: Would [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8000903/2707792) be sufficient as duplicate, in particular because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22981055/2707792)?

Comment: It might. I may need to update my question title after I understand a little better. But as of right now that answer does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't think I formed this question very well. It might be worth closing as a duplicate.

Comment: I would appreciate suggestions/edits for a better title if this question remains open.

Comment: Since expressions of shape `x.m` are called [selections](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#designators), and `_` is the "placeholder syntax", and your actual question is about type inference, how about *"How does type inference work for a selection with placeholder syntax?"*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the ordinary [function placeholder syntax](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions).

```
_.nextInt
```

is the same as

```
(_: RNG).nextInt
```

which in turn is the same as

```
(rng: RNG) => rng.nextInt
```

So, `int` is a function that takes an `RNG` as argument and returns an `Int` and the new state of `RNG` as result by invoking the method `nextInt` on the argument.

---

**Update**

The compiler can expand `_` to `(_: RNG)`, because you've explicitly specified the expected type on the left hand side of the assignment:

```
val int: Rand[Int] = ...
```

is the same as

```
val int: RNG => (Int, RNG) = ...
```

which is the same as

```
val int: Function1[RNG, (Int, RNG)] = ...
```

and the type arguments `RNG` and `(Int, RNG)` don't have to be mentioned repeatedly on the right hand side.

---

Other usages of the underscore placeholder syntax:

1. [`println(_)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415502/what-is-does-it-mean-println/52415523#52415523)

Comment: But how can that placeholder expect that the input should be of type `RNG`?  In other words how can `_.nextInt` expand to `(_: RNG).nextInt` if `RNG` is never specified anywhere?

Comment: @vaer-k It's explicitly specified in the type of `int` on the left hand side of the `=`. You don't even need any sophisticated type inference for that, even Java allowed the "diamond notation" many years ago, just so you don't have to specify all the type parameters twice.

Comment: Pardon my naivete here, but I still don't quite understand. The type specified for `int` is `Rand[Int]`, so how can the compiler infer that `RNG` should be used to produce that type?

Comment: @vaer-k `Rand[Int]` is defined as `RNG => (Int, RNG)` in the previous line, so the compiler knows that the argument type in `(x: ???) => x.nextInt` must be `RNG`.

Comment: Ahhh I see it now. Thank you. Maybe this question should be closed after all.

Comment: @jwvh Wouldn't `println _` be the eta-expansion? There is a subtle difference between the two, sometimes `f _` and `f(_)` behave slightly differently during type inference. (It's in a comment in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala#comment35079031_8001065)).

Comment: Ah, yes. Quite subtle.