# scala: append List using foldRight

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm studying the scala red book published by Manning

The List implementation is a case class:

```
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

*foldRight* is defined as:

```
def foldRight[A, B](as: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B
```

and implemented as

```
  def foldRight[A, B](as: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = { // Utility functions
    as match {
      case Nil => z
      case Cons(h, t) => f(h, foldRight(t, z)(f))
    }
  }
```

To append one List to another, my solution was:

```
  def append[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A]): List[A] 
      = foldRight(l1, l2)((l1head,l2)=>Cons(l1head, l2))
```

the answer key, however, shows the following code:

```
  def append[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A]): List[A] = foldRight(l1, l2)(Cons(_, _))
```

**Question:**
How does `(Cons(_, _))`conform to the method signature of `f: (A, B) => B`

Comment: Thanks I found my answer in you question :D It was on how to define ```foldRight``` in Scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `append()` examples are exactly the same. The 1st underscore is shorthand for "the 1st passed-in parameter" and the 2nd underscore is shorthand for "the 2nd passed-in parameter." It's just a handy way of referencing them, and passing them on to the `Cons` constructor, without the bother of giving each a name.

See also the various answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala).