# Why the type annotation is changing in Scala for one val

Tags: scala, type-annotation

Why i am getting this type annotation difference in these below scenarios.
For scenario 1

```
case class TestData(name : String , idNumber : Int)
val createRandomData : immutable.IndexedSeq[Int => TestData]= (0 to 2).map{
    _ => TestData("something",_)
  }
```

For scenario 2

```
case class TestData(name : String , idNumber : Int)
val createRandomData: immutable.Seq[TestData] = (0 to 2).map{
    i => TestData("something",i)
  }
```

Why in scenario 1 is return type is a function not a collection of Seq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do something like this:

```
    case class TestData(name : String , idNumber : Int)
    val createRandomData : immutable.IndexedSeq[Int => TestData]= (0 to 2).map{
        _ => TestData("something",_)
    }
```

the first underscore means that you ignore the value of the parameter, then you use another underscore in the body of the function passed to map so you are creation a lambda function that ends to be the return type.

What you wanted to in in first scenario was:

```
case class TestData(name : String , idNumber : Int)
val createRandomData = (0 to 2).map{
  TestData("something",_)
}
```

Which has TestData as return type.

Answer (score 3):

Because `TestData("something",i)` has type `TestData` and `TestData("something",_)` has type `Int => TestData`.

The second underscore is used for lambda (while the first underscore means that argument doesn't matter).

[What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)