# How to apply a 0-ary anonymous function to an array

Tags: arrays, scala, map-function, arity

Having an `Array` of `Int`, and a function without parameters:

```scala
scala> val a = new Array[Int](5)
a: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

scala> def f(): Int = 1
f: ()Int
```

I want to apply the function `f()` to the array with `map()` or `transform()`. I tried the following approaches.

### First approach

```scala
scala> a.map(f)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => Int
 required: Int => ?
       a.map(f)
             ^
```

It fails, which I don't really understand why.

### Second approach

```scala
scala> a.map(x => f)
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

This one works. However, I'm declaring a parameter `x` that I don't use in the right side of `=>`. It seems that anonymous functions need at least one parameter.

- Is it correct not to use `x`?
- Is it even a bad functional style?

### Practical example

To give an example on why one would use that. Imagine I have an array that at some moment I want to mutate to have random values:

```scala
val a = new Array[Int](5)
// ...
a.transform(x => random())
```

Comment: `a.map(_ => f())` Would be the best. The first option fails, because map expects a function that accepts one input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala) for ignored argument like so

```
a.map(_ => f)
```

which outputs

```
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of playing with transformations:

```
def to1[A, B](f: () => B): A => B = (_: A) =>  f()

val a = new Array[Int](5)
def f(): Int = 1
a.map(to1(f))
```

Regarding your example, consider using `fill`:

```
val b = Array.fill[Int](a.size)(myArgLessFunc())
```