# Why does the circe `or` function (an apparently unary function) work with reduceLeft which requires a binary op?

Tags: scala, methods, scala-cats, circe, arity

A and I are doing some work with circe to encode/decode some ADTs and we ran into some functionality we fundamentally don't understand. The examples given in the circe documentation work as expected, but upon drilling down - it's not clear why the decoding example works and therefore we are having a hard time reasoning about how to modify if needed.

The functionality (from [Circe Examples about ADTs](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html)):

```scala
import cats.syntax.functor._
import io.circe.{ Decoder, Encoder }, io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

object GenericDerivation {
  // Encoder Redacted

  implicit val decodeEvent: Decoder[Event] =
    List[Decoder[Event]](
      Decoder[Foo].widen,
      Decoder[Bar].widen,
      Decoder[Baz].widen,
      Decoder[Qux].widen
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
}
```

I get it - basically pick the first decoder that works from this list- makes sense BUT(!)

`or` appears to be a unary function taking a by name argument. Type signature is:

`final def or[AA >: A](d: => Decoder[AA]): Decoder[AA]`

And `reduceLeft` (from IterableOnce) requires a binary function. Type Signature is:
`def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B`

And then my brain exploded. I am clearly missing something and can't figure it out.

The example most decidedly works to convert ADTs. Why/how does this work given that the `or` function doesn't seem to be meeting the required type by `reduceLeft`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`or` is a **method** of one parameter but don't forget about `this`.

`decoder1.or(decoder2)` (aka `decoder1 or decoder2`) is a binary function with respect to `decoder1`, `decoder2`.

`+` is also a [method of one parameter](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Int.scala#L377)

```
final abstract class Int private extends AnyVal {
  ...

  /** Returns the sum of this value and `x`. */
  def +(x: Int): Int

  ...
}
```

but you can still add two `Int`s: `1 + 1` aka `1.+(1)`.

All methods have one "parameter" more than listed in their signatures, namely `this`.

(All ordinary parameters are resolved statically and `this` is resolved dynamically.)

Comment: thank you and I am now invoking self.foreheadSlap  - I was looking for the reference to `this`  earlier and totally missed it in the function implementation 
From the trait: `trait Decoder[A] extends Serializable { self =>...`

from within the `or` implementation `override def tryDecode(c: ACursor): Decoder.Result[AA] = self.tryDecode(c) ...`

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following simplified analogy

```
case class Score(v: Double) {
  def add(that: Score): Score = Score(this.v + that.v)
}

val l = List[Score](Score(1.1), Score(2.2), Score(0.1))

l.reduceLeft((a: Score, b: Score) => a.add(b))  // unsugared
l.reduceLeft((a: Score, b: Score) => a add b)   // infix notation
l.reduceLeft(_ add _)                           // anonymous function placeholder parameter
```

Note the usage of [infix notation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-1-infix-notation) and [anonymous function placeholder parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001132/5205022)