# What does _ mean in this method which already takes a default value?

Tags: scala, scala-placeholder-syntax

I am working on a test suite which has a helper method such as:

```
def setupMocks(isChild: Boolean = false): Unit
```

and in some of the tests, it is invoked as :

```
setupMocks(_)
```

whereas in other tests, it is invoked as :

```
setupMocks()
```

What does the `_` do here? What is the significance? I did try the debugger but it simply skips over and I'm unable to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is a default parameter, you can treat it both as a method with 1 and 0 parameters (kinda).

Underscores are basically placeholders for function parameters. `setupMocks(_)` is shorthand for `x => setupMocks(isChild=x)`. See [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The second example is a plain method call, calling with `isChild=false`.

Comment: So what's really happening is that `setup(_)` returns a function which accepts one parameter and return `Unit`. Which is entirely different from `setupMocks()` which makes the actual call to the method!