# Underscore in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I've learnt Scala for 1,5 months at the university - what I had is: collections, pattern matching, functions on collections but my question is: what does really that underscore mean?
I saw you guys using it almost everywhere and I don't know how to read it to be honest.
For example:

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3,4,5)
list1.map(_ * 2) or list1.map(n => n*2)
```

what's the difference there? What could be hidden under that underscore symbol?
I saw you guys also using almost always in `reduceLeft(_ + _)` something like this - how could I replace that to see, what is hidden under that?

I also have question if you recommend that page: [www.scala-exercises.org](http://www.scala-exercises.org) to practice and learn Scala? I can't create any exercises myself and would like to practice more exercise than I get on lessons.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/placeholder-syntax-in-scala/#:~:text=Scala%20allows%20the%20use%20of,for%20one%20or%20more%20parameters.&text=Multiple%20underscores%20means%20multiple%20parameters,or%20more%20parameters%20only%20once.) help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

Underscores used to replace the N'th argument with an anonymous argument in a function, for example, the following lines are equivalent

```
list1.map(_ * 2)
list1.map(n => n * 2)
```

Regarding the `reduceLeft(_ + _)`, so as said before, its replacing the 1'th argument and 2'th argument as follows, thus they are equivalent

```
list1.reduceLeft(_ + _)
list1.reduceLeft((a,b) => a + b)
```

And so on...

Hope its clear now

Comment: thank you, but about the reduce it's quite difficult for me: so under first underscore I have (a,b) => a, and under second one I have only b?

Comment: Please, do not answer duplicate questions. If you are *really* confident that there is something important missing that is not yet covered in one of the 13 answers that already exist on the duplicate target, then write an answer *over there*. Answering duplicate questions spreads the information out across multiple places which is the *exact opposite* of what [so] tries to do, namely provide the highest-quality possible information in a single place.