# How _._2 works in Map to find?

Tags: scala

I've below Map

```
Object DataMapping
 val myMap = Map(DataGroup.REAL-> SEQ(A,B,C),
                 DataGroup.PEAL-> SEQ(H,J,K,L,M),
                 DataGroup.CEAL-> SEQ(X,Y))
```

And this snippet is being used to find in above map. Struggling to understand what's `_._2 and _._1` is doing in this code, how its behaving and what will be the output for this ?

```
DataMapping.myMap.find(_._2.contains(Y)).map(_._1).get
```

I'm new in scala and tried reading online too but couldn't understand. Can anyone please share ?

Comment: [This here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001132/2707792) contains answers to both parts of your question. You're looking for "Anonymous function placeholder parameter" and "Part of a method name, such as tuple getters".

Answer (score 5):

The two underscores mean different things. First off, a bare underscore as part of a function argument will get turned into a lambda expression (see [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)). So your code

```
DataMapping.myMap.find(_._2.contains(Y)).map(_._1).get
```

is equivalent to

```
DataMapping.myMap.find(x => x._2.contains(Y)).map(x => x._1).get
```

Now, all of the sequencing functions, such as `find` and `map`, act on 2-tuples `(K, V)` when applied to a `Map[K, V]`. We're iterating over pairs, where the first element of the pair is the key and the second is the value. In Scala, we can access the Nth element (1-indexed) of a tuple with `_N`, so if we have a pair `val myPair = ("a", "b")`, then `myPair._1` is `"a"` and `myPair._2` is `"b"`.

The `.find` call is checking whether the *value* (i.e. the second element of the pair) contains `Y`. `.find` returns an `Option[(K, V)]`, since we were iterating over a sequence of `(K, V)`. Now `Option` is a container like any other, just with the restriction that it can contain at most one element. So `Option.map` has the net effect of applying a function to the inside of the `Option` (if it exists) and doing nothing if given `None`. In our case, we've got an `Option[(K, V)]` and we just care about the first part, so we want an `Option[K]`. If there's something in the `Option`, we do `x => x._1` to get the first element of that tuple. If there's `None`, then we just keep the value as `None`.

`Option.get` is an assertion that the `Option` is non-empty. It throws an exception if that's wrong.

In summary, that code takes the map `DataMapping.myMap`, finds the first element of your mapping whose *value* contains `Y`, and then gets the corresponding key, throwing an exception if we can't find any such element.

Since we do a `.get` right after, the `.map` is sort of pointless in this case. I would probably have written this code as

```
DataMapping.myMap.find(_._2.contains(Y)).get._1
```

And, personally, I'm not super fond of the `_N` syntax to begin with, so I might have gone one step further.

```
val (key, _) = DataMapping.myMap.find((_, v) => v.contains(Y)).get
```

or, in Scala 2 (before we had automatic case destructuring)

```
val (key, _) = DataMapping.myMap.find { case (_, v) => v.contains(Y) }.get
```

Comment: x._2 is value and x._1 key of Map ?

Comment: It probably should be noted that the `find((_, v) => ...)` part works in 3.x, but wouldn't work in 2.x, you'd need a `{ case (_, v) => ... }` there.

Also, `get` is a code smell; If you want to process the `Option` properly, you probably want to handle it in a `for-yield`, so you can do the pattern-matching inside of the `for` as well.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Oops! I've been spoiled by Scala 3 for so long now I've already forgotten what it used to be. Thanks!